# Regex para encontrar ocorrências de uma palavra antes da outra

Tags: regex

Preciso encontrar nos fontes do sistema situações onde **TAction** ocorra depois de **TdxBar**.

Isso irá acontecer em linhas diferentes, mas dentro do mesmo arquivo, por exemplo:

```
pnlVisao: TPanel;
tbToolBar: TdxBar;
btnCancelar: TButton;
actAbrir: TAction;
```

Neste caso a action está declarada depois da toolbar.

Tentei utilizar `/(TdxBar)(?=TAction)/g` mas não funcionou.

Comment: Em qual linguagem você vai usá-la?

Comment: Ia rodar no sublime ou no atom. É para pesquisar para realizar uma correção

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pelo que pesquisei tem uma flag para usar no Sublime que faz com que a regex seja multiline.

Tente com a Regex:

```
(?s)TdxBar.*?TAction
```

O `(?s)` diz ao Sublime que a regex é multiline fazendo com que o `.` também case com quebras de linha.

Fonte:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11992596/regex-in-sublime-text-match-any-character-including-newlines

---

**Edit (2018-09-19)**

Esbarrei com explicações na internet recentemente e decidi complementar esta resposta.

[Este post](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/whats-sublimes-new-regex-engine/18944/3) no fórum do Sublime pergunta sobre uma nova *engine* para regex implementada no software. O criador do [package control](https://packagecontrol.io/) responde que a nova engine é utilizada para *sintax highlight* e lendo o post se descobre que a biblioteca [Oniguruma](https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma) é usada no Sublime Text.

Entrando no repositório, encontrei [onde é documentada a flag `(?s)`](https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma/blob/92354eea3ff8f07795c3ddb91cc6886c54578f10/doc/RE#L501):

```
+ ONIG_SYNTAX_PERL and ONIG_SYNTAX_JAVA
    (?s): dot (.) also matches newline
    (?m): ^ matches after newline, $ matches before newline
```

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado

Comment: cool! +1 ......

Comment: Não sabia que o Sublime suportava o `(?s)`, eu costumava usar a regex [que sugeri abaixo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/396992/112052) :-)

Comment: Também fiquei surpreso quando descobri na época. Nunca precisei usar, descobri pesquisando para essa pergunta. :D

Answer (score 3):

Se a intenção for encontrar a lista dos ficheiros que contêm o referido padrão
sugeria:

```
grep  -zPl 'TdxBar(.|\n)*TAction' *
```

- `-z` O opção -z (null separated records) faz com que o ficheiro seja carregado como
  se fosse uma única linha; deste modo as expressões regulares podem ser multilingues
- `-l` diz apenas os nomes dos ficheiros que contêm ocorrências do padrão
- `-P`expressões regulares extendidas em sintaxe Perl

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a [resposta do fernandosavio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/54067/112052), uma outra alternativa é usar a regex:

```
TdxBar[\s\S]+TAction
```

Em vez do ponto, eu uso `[\s\S]`.

Os colchetes definem uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) e correspondem a qualquer caractere que esteja dentro deles. Por exemplo, `[ab]` significa "a letra `a` **ou** a letra `b`".

No caso, dentro dos colchetes temos:

- `\s`: um [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) que corresponde a espaços, quebra de linha, <kbd>TAB</kbd>, etc ([a lista exata de caracteres pode variar de acordo com a linguagem/engine utilizada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405703/112052)).
- `\S`: qualquer coisa que não seja um `\s`

Portanto, `[\s\S]` é "qualquer coisa que seja espaço, quebras de linha, etc, **ou** qualquer coisa que não seja isso". Resumindo, isso acaba correspondendo a qualquer caractere, incluindo as quebras de linha.

No fim, acaba tendo o mesmo efeito de usar `.` junto com a *flag* `(?s)` (o ponto, por padrão, [corresponde a qualquer caractere, exceto quebras de linha](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html), e a flag `(?s)` muda este comportamento, fazendo com que também corresponda a quebras de linha).

Eu também uso o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`, que significa "uma ou mais ocorrências". Isso faz com que tenha que ter pelo menos um caractere entre "TdxBar" e "TAction".

Se você usar `*` (zero ou mais ocorrências), a regex também vai considerar os casos em que não tem nada entre eles (ou seja, se tiver "TdxBarTAction" no texto, a regex com `*` pega, mas a com `+` não, pois o `+` exige que haja pelo menos um caractere entre eles).

---

Por padrão, os quantificadores como `*` e `+` são [gananciosos](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) e tentam pegar o máximo possível de caracteres. Isso quer dizer que, caso hajam duas ocorrências de "TdxBar" e "TAction", a regex pegará todo o trecho entre o primeiro "TdxBar" e o último "TAction".

Se você sabe que eles só ocorrem no máximo uma vez no texto, e se você só quer saber se um está antes do outro, não há problema. Mas caso queira que a regex pegue todos os trechos isoladamente, basta cancelar a ganância usando um `?` depois do `+`:

```
TdxBar[\s\S]+?TAction
```

Assim, o quantificador se torna [preguiçoso](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) e tenta pegar o mínimo de caracteres possível. Veja a diferença: [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/aR3EV6/1/) o quantificador preguiçoso encontra 2 *matches*, já [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/aR3EV6/2/) a versão gananciosa encontra apenas um *match*.