# O que significa o atalho \s nas REGEX?

Tags: regex, espaço-em-branco

Vejo muitas pessoas usando `\s` nas regex achando que seu significado é `' '` (espaço) pois lhes digo, não é, ao menos não só isso.

Mas então o que significa o `\s` em REGEX?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

O `\s` abrange muito mais que o `' '` (espaço).

```
\s = [ \t\n\r\f\v]
```

- `' '` (espaço)
- `\t` TAB
- `\n` new line (quebra de linha)
- `\r` retono de carro (volta o cursos para o inicio da linha)
- `\f` avanço de pagina
- `\v` [vertical TAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380538/what-is-a-vertical-tab/3380554#3380554) - (usado em configuraçoes de impressora)

Answer (score 9):

A lista de caracteres que o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s` considera pode variar de uma linguagem/API/ferramenta/*engine* para outra, e até mesmo de acordo com as configurações disponíveis em cada uma.

De modo geral, o `\s` sempre considera os seguintes caracteres:

- o [espaço em branco](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0020/index.htm)
- o <kbd>TAB</kbd> (`\t`) (também chamado de "horizontal tab" ou ["CHARACTER TABULATION"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0009/index.htm))
- o *new line* (`\n`) (também conhecido como [LINE FEED](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000a/index.htm))
- o [*carriage return* (`\r`)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000d/index.htm)
- e o [*form feed* (`\f`)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000c/index.htm)

O *vertical tab* (`\v`) (ou ["LINE TABULATION"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/000b/index.htm)) também é considerado em várias linguagens, como [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#predef), [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes#Types), [Ruby](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Metacharacters+and+Escapes) e [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-30).

Mas em PHP, por exemplo, o `\s` não considera o *vertical tab*. Segundo a [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php):

> `\s`  any whitespace character
>
> The "whitespace" characters are HT (9), LF (10), FF (12), CR (13), and space (32)

Ou seja, só inclui o HT (*horizontal tab*), LF (*line feed*), FF (*form feed*), CR (*carriage return*) e o espaço.

E em Perl, o *vertical tab* só foi adicionado na versão 5.18, conforme indicado na [documentação](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html):

> `\s` means the five characters `[ \f\n\r\t]`, and **starting in Perl v5.18, the vertical tab**;

Enfim, em cada linguagem, API ou ferramenta/*engine*, esta lista pode variar (o Google Docs, por exemplo, [usa a *engine* RE2](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en), que [não considera o *vertibal tab*](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt)), então sempre consulte a documentação para ter certeza.

---

## Unicode

Além disso, muitas linguagens possuem configurações que ativam o "modo Unicode", o que faz com que o `\s` corresponda a muitos outros caracteres além dos já citados.

Por exemplo, em Java, se a regex estiver com a opção [`UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS), o `\s` corresponde a todos os [caracteres que possuem a propriedade Unicode `White_Space`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode) (a lista pode ser consultada diretamente [aqui](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/PropList.txt)). Então este código:

```java
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\s", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS).matcher("");
// loop por todos os code points do Unicode
for (int i = 0; i <= Character.MAX_CODE_POINT; i++) {
    String s = new String(new int[] { i }, 0, 1);
    matcher.reset(s);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        // se corresponde a \s, imprime o codepoint e o nome do caractere
        System.out.printf("%06X, %s\n", i, Character.getName(i));
    }
}
```

Gera a seguinte saída:

```
000009, CHARACTER TABULATION
00000A, LINE FEED (LF)
00000B, LINE TABULATION
00000C, FORM FEED (FF)
00000D, CARRIAGE RETURN (CR)
000020, SPACE
000085, NEXT LINE (NEL)
0000A0, NO-BREAK SPACE
001680, OGHAM SPACE MARK
002000, EN QUAD
002001, EM QUAD
002002, EN SPACE
002003, EM SPACE
002004, THREE-PER-EM SPACE
002005, FOUR-PER-EM SPACE
002006, SIX-PER-EM SPACE
002007, FIGURE SPACE
002008, PUNCTUATION SPACE
002009, THIN SPACE
00200A, HAIR SPACE
002028, LINE SEPARATOR
002029, PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR
00202F, NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE
00205F, MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE
003000, IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE
```

<sup>[Veja aqui](http://ideone.com/FZnbZ8) este código rodando.</sup>

Agora, se retirarmos a opção `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`, o *default* é considerar somente os 6 caracteres já citados (`[ \t\n\r\f\v]`):

```java
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\s").matcher("");
... restante do código igual
```

A saída passa a ser:

```
000009, CHARACTER TABULATION
00000A, LINE FEED (LF)
00000B, LINE TABULATION
00000C, FORM FEED (FF)
00000D, CARRIAGE RETURN (CR)
000020, SPACE
```

<sup>[Veja aqui](http://ideone.com/BNYdci) este código rodando.</sup>

---

Em Python também existe algo similar, porém em Python 3 o comportamento é o oposto do Java. Por *default*, a regex já está em "modo Unicode" e o [atalho `\s`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-30) considera todos os *Unicode whitespace characters*. Fazendo um código similar ao exemplo anterior:

```py
import unicodedata as u
import re

r = re.compile(r'\s')
for i in range(0x10ffff + 1):
    s = chr(i)
    if r.search(s):
        print('{:02X} {}'.format(i, u.name(s, '')))
```

Por *default*, esta regex está em "modo Unicode". A saída é:

```
09 
0A 
0B 
0C 
0D 
1C 
1D 
1E 
1F 
20 SPACE
85 
A0 NO-BREAK SPACE
1680 OGHAM SPACE MARK
2000 EN QUAD
2001 EM QUAD
2002 EN SPACE
2003 EM SPACE
2004 THREE-PER-EM SPACE
2005 FOUR-PER-EM SPACE
2006 SIX-PER-EM SPACE
2007 FIGURE SPACE
2008 PUNCTUATION SPACE
2009 THIN SPACE
200A HAIR SPACE
2028 LINE SEPARATOR
2029 PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR
202F NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE
205F MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE
3000 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE
```

<sup>[Veja aqui](https://ideone.com/sxAW1G) este código rodando.</sup>

Já se usarmos a [*flag* `ASCII`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.ASCII), o `\s` passa a considerar apenas os caracteres  `[ \t\n\r\f\v]`:

```py
r = re.compile(r'\s', re.ASCII)
... restante do código igual
```

Saída:

```
09 
0A 
0B 
0C 
0D 
20 SPACE
```

<sup>[Veja aqui](https://ideone.com/0BhdAu) este código rodando.</sup>

Obs: no [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html) o comportamento é o mesmo do Java. Por *default*, o `\s` equivale apenas aos caracteres `[ \f\n\r\v\t]` ([veja](https://ideone.com/NAvibh)), e o "modo Unicode" é habilitado usando-se a [*flag* `UNICODE`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.UNICODE) ([veja](https://ideone.com/SFFUyV)).

---

Outro detalhe é que o Python retornou 4 caracteres a mais que o Java ([1C](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1c/index.htm), [1D](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d/index.htm), [1E](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1e/index.htm) e [1F](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f/index.htm)). *Talvez* seja por causa da versão do Unicode que cada um usa internamente (testei com Java 8, [que usa o Unicode 6.2.0](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/enhancements.8.html#unicode), e Python 3.8, [que usa o Unicode 12.1.0](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/unicodedata.html)), **ou** devido a algum detalhe interno de implementação de cada linguagem, que leva ou não em conta outros fatores, além da propriedade `White_Space`. De qualquer forma, isso serve para confirmar que o comportamento do atalho `\s` de fato varia de acordo com a linguagem utilizada.

E até mesmo bibliotecas diferentes da mesma linguagem podem ter comportamentos diferentes. Por exemplo, se eu mudar o código acima para usar o [módulo `regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) (um excelente módulo que estende as funcionalidades do módulo `re`), [a lista de caracteres retornada é a mesma do código Java](https://repl.it/@hkotsubo/QuaintCumbersomeBase#main.py).

---

#### Considerações finais

Outras linguagens e ferramentas podem ou não ter suporte ao "modo Unicode" (que por sua vez pode ou não ser o modo *default*), e podem ou não disponibilizar uma opção para habilitá-lo ou desabilitá-lo (outras ainda podem ter suporte às propriedades Unicode, como por exemplo `\p{IsWhite_Space}` para procurar todos os *Unicode whitespace characters*, que pode ou não ser equivalente a `\s`). Por isso, sempre vale a pena ler a documentação para se certificar quanto à lista de caracteres que o `\s` considera (*como um adendo, o mesmo vale para outros atalhos, como `\d`, `\w`, `\b`, etc, pois seus comportamentos também podem variar e eles podem ser afetados - ou não - de acordo com a linguagem/engine e seus modos de configuração*).

Claro que, se você está trabalhando com entradas controladas e "sabe" muito bem quais os caracteres que o texto possui e quais ele não possui, pode ser que não faça muita diferença usar `\s` no modo Unicode ou não, ou usar um espaço simples na regex. Mas é importante saber as implicações de usá-lo, pois há casos em que você pode ter resultados diferentes (por exemplo, se você só quer considerar os espaços, mas não as quebras de linha, aí faz diferença usá-lo).

Por fim, algumas linguagens suportam outros atalhos similares, como as *POSIX character classes*. Por exemplo, [em Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#posix) é possível usar `\p{Blank}`, e [em PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) é possível usar `[:blank:]`, e ambos correspondem a `[ \t]` (um espaço ou <kbd>TAB</kbd>) - embora em Java este também mude quando está no "modo Unicode". Ainda há *engines* que suportam o atalho `\R`, que corresponde a quebras de linha (mas ainda sim com diferenças; por exemplo, [em Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lineending) ele corresponde a `\u000D\u000A|[\u000A\u000B\u000C\u000D\u0085\u2028\u2029]`, e [em PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) ele só considera `\r`, `\n` ou `\r\n`).

Dependendo do caso, usar essas variações - quando disponíveis - pode ser melhor do que usar `\s` (por exemplo, se eu quero ignorar - ou considerar somente - as quebras de linha).

---

Por fim, vale mencionar também o atalho `\S` (com "S" maiúsculo), que é basicamente "qualquer caractere que **não** seja `\s`" (isso segue um padrão comum em regex, que é ter um atalho "oposto", como por exemplo o `\D` que é "qualquer caractere que não seja `\d`", ou `\W` para "qualquer caractere que não seja `\w`").