# Duvida replace função javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, segurança

Galera alguem pode me explicar  o que significa esses parâmetros dentro da função `replace  (/</g)  , (http:\/\/\S+)/g`

```
function escape(s) {


  var text = s.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace('"', '&quot;');


  // URLs
  text = text.replace(/(http:\/\/\S+)/g, '<a href="$1">$1</a>');


  // [[img123|Description]]


  text = text.replace(/\[\[(\w+)\|(.+?)\]\]/g, '<img alt="$2" src="$1.gif">');


  return text;


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ambos são instruções regex, considerando o código que você mesmo forneceu elas estão sendo utilizadas para substituir o conteúdo html indesejado de determinadas strings.

```
/</g
```

Tem por finalidade identificar as incidências do carácter `<` e o `g` especifica que a consulta deve ser efetuada na string inteira

Considerando a aplicação no seu código ela está substituindo as incidências de  '<' pelo seu equivalento em ASCII code '<' em geral isso serve para evitar que os navegadores não entendam o caracter '<' como código html.

```
http:\/\/\S+
```

Tem por finalidade identificar as incidências de palavras que comecem com `http://` e o `S+` informa que o http:// pode ser seguido de qualquer caracter que não seja um espaço.

Considerando a aplicação do seu código este teria por finalidade remover as incidências de urls da string.

É valido ressaltar que todas essas instruções regex estão bem mal escritas e pouco restringidas, resumindo provavelmente iriam substituir muita coisa indesejada

Comment: Dica de leitura : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110701/o-que-significa-o-atalho-s-nas-regex