# Carácteres de escape

Tags: c#

Estou com dificuldades para compreender os caracteres de escape, já sei que o **`\n`** quebra linha em uma string, mas os outros caracteres não consegui entender.

Ex: **`\a \b \f \r \t \v`**, encontrei a [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/h21280bw.aspx) da Microsoft e não tem muitos exemplos.

Gostaria de ver alguns exemplos em C# e explicações se possível.

Comment: Uma vez eu fiz isso : [Cola 1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jBB77.png), [Cola 2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/f1gna.png), nem todas linguagens implementam igual, e quando fiz foi para REGEX. Use como base, não fato.

Comment: Boa tarde, Samuel. Dê uma conferida aqui: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371232/Escaping-in-Csharp-characters-strings-string-forma Abraços e bons estudos!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suponha que você esteja fazendo um pequeno programa para testar esses caracteres de escape, e queira imprimir na tela. Bons exemplos para começar são `\"` e `\'`.

[Fiz o seguinte Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MrAGrK):

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\"");
        Console.WriteLine("\'");
    }
}
```

O resultado vai ser:

```
"
'
```

A ideia dos caracteres de escape é dizer ao interpretador:

> Uma aspa ou um apóstrofo com uma barra invertida na frente não devem ser tratados como símbolos especiais, e sim, como sua representação literal, ou ainda o inverso: dado o símbolo na seuqência de escape, ele passa a ter um sentido especial.

A sequência de escape, portanto, anula o propósito especial que um símbolo possui numa linguagem, ou ainda expressa de outra forma um símbolo cuja representação seja abstrata ou ambígua em um determinado contexto, como símbolos de espaço e tabulação (`\s` e `\t`, respectivamente).

Suponha agora uma `String` completamente "vazia" (mas que na verdade esteja preechida por espaços e *tabs*) e que eu queira contar quantos espaços e quantos *tabs* existem dentro dela. [Uma forma de fazer isso](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vtwhJA) é:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        String tabsEEspacos = "                                                             ";
        Console.WriteLine(Regex.Matches(tabsEEspacos, @"\s").Count);
    }
}
```

`\s` conta todos os espaços (no exemplo, 23) e `\t` conta apenas os que são tabulações de fato (16). Experimente trocar no exemplo.

Casos como `\a` e `\b` se aplicam bem ao esperar comandos de teclado do usuário ou acionar o *hardware* (caso específico de `\a`).

Sequências de escape em ASCII e Unicode são úteis para conversão de formatos, de um para o outro, por exemplo.

Comment: Relacionado : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110701/o-que-significa-o-atalho-s-nas-regex

Comment: Entendo, mas e no caso de \f \r \v ?

Comment: @samuelrvg, a questão tem mais a ver com texto em si do que com o c#; `\f` = formfeed , muda de página em impressoras e paginadores; `\r\n` = muda de linha em windows ; `\v` = vertical tab, mais raramente usado para separar verticalmente pedaços de texto

Answer (score 2):

Sequência de escape é uma combinação de caracteres consistindo de uma contra barra `\` seguida por uma letra ou por combinações de dígitos. É usada na representação de caracteres de controle como CR, apóstrofe, etc..

As sequências de escape permitem o envio de caracteres de controle não gráficos para dispositivos de impressão. 
O caractere `ESC` é frequentemente usado como caractere inicial de um comando de controle para a impressora ou para um terminal de vídeo, ou seja, sequência de escape.

Segue abaixo um resumo sobre os caracteres especiais mais utilizadas em programação:

```
\a - BEL Bell
\b - BS (ascii) BackSpace
\f - FF Formfeed
\n - LF NewLine
\r - CR Carriage Return
\t - HT Horizontal Tabulation
\v - VT (ascii) Vertical Tabulation
\' - Apóstrofe (Single quotation mark)
\" - Aspas (Double quotation mark)
\\ - Contrabarra
\ooo - Caracter ASCII em notação octal
\xhhh - Caracter ASCII em notação hexadecimal
```

Espero ter ajudado.