# Por que a regex não funciona?

Tags: php, regex

Estou seguindo a apostila [OOP Programming with PHP5](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjvxPXuxrfLAhVEHpAKHW_8BIQQFggfMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftinoweb.googlecode.com%2Ffiles%2FOO%2520Programming%2520with%2520PHP5.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFnzqsf8-4SEDy-BSERSb_zAxiPcg&sig2=M5qXFJVZW8MBnUon0sMDHQ) por Hasin Hayder (2007) e cheguei na parte de Unit Tests. Em dado exercício, ele monta um método `wordCount()` e cria alguns testes para este método,

```
class WordCount
{
    public function countWords($sentence)
    {
        return count(split(" ",$sentence));
    }
}
```

que retorna todas as palavras da variável, ou seja: `$this->assertEquals(4, $wordcount);`, se a variável for algo tipo: `"my name is john"` ele terá quatro palavras.

Ele cria um teste para o caso de a variável ter mais espaços: `"my name is john "` (perceba o espaço depois de John), que quando a gente roda retorna `Failure`.

Para resolver, ele modifica o método e adiciona o `preg_replace` e aquela regex ali `"~\s+~"` e o código dele funciona como o esperado, porém, **usei a mesma coisa e não funcionou**.

Ele ainda cria um outro teste, onde a variável é `"my name is \n\r john"` e a mesma regex deu conta.

```
class WordCount
{
    public function countWords($sentence)
    {
        $newsentence = preg_replace("~\s+~"," ",$sentence);
        return count(split(" ",$newsentence));
    }
}
```

Já verifiquei meu código afim de encontrar possíveis erros de sintaxe ou estrutura, mas está tudo ok, pelo menos, igual o que ele manda no exercício.

Para resolver os 2 primeiros testes, eu achei `preg_replace('/\s*$/','',$sentence);` que funcionou, mas o teste onde há o `\n\r` não passou.

Então gostaria de saber:

1. Por que o regex que ele usou não funcionou?
2. Como seria uma regex que retira os espaços a mais e o carriage return/new line (`\n\r`);

Os códigos completos usados estão aqui:

- [Teste](https://github.com/wdarkin/php_exercises/blob/master/chapter5/class.testwordcount.php)
- [Método](https://github.com/wdarkin/php_exercises/blob/master/chapter5/class.wordcount.php)

Comment: Qual a ligação da pergunta com o phpunit e testes unitário? Se a pergunta não é relacionada diretamente com eles, é melhor [edit] e remover essas tags

Comment: Mas emitiu alguma mensagem de erro com a palavra "deprecated"? Porque algo não funcionar não quer dizer que esteja em desuso. Amanhã eu tento entender o problema.

Comment: gmsantos, ja removi. Guilherme, não apareceu nenhum erro com "deprecated", o teste apenas não passou no phpunit. No tutorial, passa, mas quando eu fiz, não deu

Comment: Se não aparece nada de "deprecated" por que o título da pergunta cita isso?

Comment: porque é a duvida que eu tenho. a regex "~\s+~" foi depreciada? porque eu acredito que o phpunit não mostraria erros relacionados a isto, logo suponho que este formato de regex esteja antigo/depreciado.

Comment: A regex está ok para o PHP. Acabei de testar seu código, o problema é outro, estou respondendo.

Comment: O @gmsantos já esta respondendo, eu ia dizer `split` é que esta em desuso veja: http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php

Comment: Recomendação de leitura : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110701/o-que-significa-o-atalho-s-nas-regex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ao tentar executar seu código tive o seguinte retorno:

```
<?php

function countWords($sentence)
{
    $newsentence = preg_replace("/\s+/"," ",$sentence);
    return count(split(" ", $newsentence));
}

echo countWords("my name is john");
echo countWords("my name \n\r is john");
echo countWords("my name \n is john");
echo countWords("my name \n\n\r is john");
```

> Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in /in/MSmEj on line 6
>
> 4
>
> Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in /in/MSmEj on line 6
>
> 4
>
> Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in /in/MSmEj on line 6
>
> 4
>
> Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in /in/MSmEj on line 6
>
> 4

Temos ai o primeiro sintoma que tem algo errado. A função [`split()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.split.php) foi descontinuada. Isso não quer dizer de ela não vá funcionar. Porém ela espera uma outra expressão regular para quebrar sua string, e você está passando um espaço em branco, que não é a mesma coisa de um [meta caractere de espaço](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_whitespace.asp) `\s` para as regex.

A regex `~\s+~` em si é valida. O PHP [aceita qualquer caracter não alfanumérico ou espaços em branco](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) como delimitador da regex. Geralmente são usados `//` em regex. Note também que `'/\s*$/'` é uma regex completamente diferente de `/\s+/`, basicamente por [causa dos quantificadores](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) `+` e `*`. Por fim, prefira aspas simples ao utilizar regex. No seu exemplo você usa aspas duplas, o que não é o ideal.

Você pode refatorar esse método para usar `preg_split`:

```
function countWords($sentence)
{
    return count(preg_split('~\s+~', $sentence));
}
```

Por fim, fica um ponto de atenção. **Procure estudar com materiais atualizados**. O livro em questão é de 2007 e muita coisa mudou no PHP nesses 9 anos. A chance de você estar aprendendo algo que não é mais usado atualmente é muito grande.

---

Analisando melhor, o problema com esse caso de teste é mesmo a implementação. O `split` do caso do espaço extra vai mesmo retornar um array com 5 elementos, sendo a ultima posição uma string vazia.

Para chegar no resultado esperado, dê um `trim()` antes na `$sentence`

```
return count(preg_split('~\s+~', trim($sentence)));
```

Comment: +1 pela resposta completa, porém ainda no meu caso "My name is John " <- com o espaço, retorna o valor 5, quando deveria retornar o valor 4, logo, o teste retorna `Failure`. Se não for incomodo, poderia ver o código no github? [Teste](https://github.com/wdarkin/php_exercises/blob/master/chapter5/class.testwordcount.php) e [Método](https://github.com/wdarkin/php_exercises/blob/master/chapter5/class.wordcount.php)

Comment: @wdarking O gmsantos editou a resposta com um exemplo com `trim`.

Comment: funcionou. acredito que na apostila haja algum erro de formatação sobre o espaço, porquê ele apenas usa a regex e escapa o ultimo espaço, mas acredito que o trim seja a solução mais correta. obrigado.

Comment: @wdarking como o gmsantos, essa apostila é antigade 9 anos atrás, usar ela vai te ensinar caminhos errados que hoje não usamos mais.