# Eliminar linhas em branco

Tags: regex, sublime-text

Estou com um texto que está com uma estrutura assim:

```
AJUSTE_ESTOQUE

AJUSTE_PRODUCAO

AJUSTE_QUALIDADE

AMOSTRA
```

Eu fiz uma `regex` (`^\s*$`) para localizar estas linhas em branco, como posso remover elas a fim que cada palavra fique embaixo da outra ? Estou usando o `sublime` para este trabalho.

Comment: Poste seu código por favor Douglas!

Comment: Coloquei a regex que usei.

Comment: Leitura recomendada : [**O que significa o atalho \s nas REGEX?**](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110701/14213)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pressione o atalho <kbd>CTRL+H</kbd> ou entre em *Find/Replace*. Busque por `^\s*` no campo *Find What* e substitua por nada (deixe o campo *Replace With* em branco).

Certifique-se de habilitar a busca por expressões regulares através do botão `E`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pressione o botão *Replace All* e seu resultado será:

```
AJUSTE_ESTOQUE
AJUSTE_PRODUCAO
AJUSTE_QUALIDADE
AMOSTRA
```

> Alguns termos podem variar conforme o idioma utilizado no editor.

Comment: Obrigado :), show.

Comment: `^\s*` vai substituir todos os espaços do início de cada linha, não apenas linhas em branco.

Comment: @Mariano está correto, o mais apropriado seria `^[\s\t]*$` assim irá realmente irá substituir somente as linhas vazias.

Comment: Olá @gleisin-dev. O \s considera o \t, da forma feita é redundância. O $ nos editores de texto provavelmente vai depender da forma usada, se é seleção multi-line ou não. No caso o $ no regex já resolveria no caso de linhas em sequencia pelo padrão do sublime, mas não posso afirmar isso para outros editores.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Ah, entendi!