# Função regex espaços em branco SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

Olá,

Dentro de uma tabela específica no meu DB, tenho certos campos que foram cadastrados por outrem (usuários), então, alguns campos ao invés de possuírem um simples espaço `' '`, possui espaços dos mais diversos tipos! Faço o tratamento no Javascript da seguinte forma:

```
/\s/g
```

Porém, gostaria de criar uma função dentro do SQL Server que fizesse este tipo de tratamento. É possível? Procurei aqui no fórum algo semelhante mas nada efetivo e, tentei criar uma função por meio da sintaxe acima mas sem resultados.

Obrigado!

Comment: @Marconi mas caso haja um outro tipo de "espaço", como por exemplo uma tabulação, ele vai remover tbm? Estou sem sql agora pra testar

Comment: @jvbarsou fiz o testo com uma tabulação e funcionou, uma tabulação dentro do `Sql-Management` considerou com 1 espaço, agora já duas essa solução não trata.

Comment: @jvbarsou tenta pegar essa minha solução e adapta na respsota do Juliet dessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580017/how-to-replace-multiple-characters-in-sql) do SO-EN.

Comment: Sugestão de leitura : [O que significa o atalho \s nas REGEX](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110701/14213)

Answer (score 0):

Tente da forma abaixo, podendo utilizar como uma função.

```
Declare @Texto1 varchar(100),
        @TextoTemp varchar(100),
        @Tamanho Integer,
        @Posicao Integer

Set @Texto1= 'pro paro xiton  a'
Set @Tamanho=Len(@Texto1)
Set @Posicao=1
Set @TextoTemp = ''

While @Posicao <= @Tamanho
Begin
   If SubString(@Texto1,@Posicao,1) <> ' '
      Begin
         Set @TextoTemp = @TextoTemp + SubString(@Texto1,@Posicao,1)
      end

   Set @Posicao = @Posicao+1
end

SELECT @TextoTemp
```