# Separar strings por ponto e vírgula mas também guardar o ponto e vírgula

Tags: java, regex

Estou utilizando o split para separar strings por espaço, enter e ponto e vírgula, porém, quando for o ponto e vírgula preciso guardar ele em uma posição do array também. Como fazer isto?

Código Atual:

```
String[] textoSeparado = texto.split(" |\\n|;");
```

Comment: Não ficou claro o que você quer. Coloque um exemplo de entrada e um exemplo de saída. Além disso, sua dúvida não é relacionada ao Android (nem ao Android Studio), apenas ao Java. Estou removendo as tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Após ler algumas vezes, acho que entendi o que pretende:

> separar uma string utilizando espaço(" "), quebra de linha(\n ou \r) e ponto e virgula(;) como delimitadores, mas incluindo o `;` como um item da lista.

Se estiver certo, consegui combinar uma regex que atenda a essas condições, e o resultado foi:

```
String[] stringSeparada = teste.split("((?<=;)|(?=;))|\\s");
```

Veja o teste abaixo:

```
//dois exemplos com ambos os tipos de quebras de linhas(windows/linux)
String teste = ";espaco pontoevirgula;QUEBRA\ndelinha;";
String teste2 = ";espaco pontoevirgula;QUEBRA\rdelinha;";
String regex = "((?<=;)|(?=;))|\\s";

String[] stringSeparada = teste.split(regex);
String[] stringSeparada2 = teste2.split(regex);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringSeparada));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringSeparada2));
```

Saida:

> [;, espaco, pontoevirgula, ;, QUEBRA, delinha, ;]
>   [;, espaco, pontoevirgula, ;, QUEBRA, delinha, ;]

Repare que a regex irá capturar o `;` independente de onde ela apareça.

Veja funcionando online no [**IDEONE**](https://ideone.com/sH8IdP).

---

#### Referências:

- [How can I split a string in Java and retain the delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3777599/5524514)
- [How to split a string, but also keep the delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2206432/5524514)
- [Java Regex Doc(Classe Pattern)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: Obrigado, era exatamente isto. Eu não sei muito sobre expressões regulares, então teria como me explicar este trecho que você criou? Pois gostaria de acrescentar esta regra do ponto e vírgula para outros símbolos.

Comment: @LucasFernando  o primeiro grupo verifica se o ponto e vírgula está na string , mas não consome caso ele seja encontrado. Quanto ao problema relatado, sempre prefira comentar na resposta, eu vou tentar simular pra ver como resolver.

Comment: @LucasFernando o problema que vc relatou de travar caso o ; esteja no final não ocorre, veja: https://ideone.com/SALmmy

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/PhCFTg/1/, só resumi um pouco.

Comment: aproveitando, agora olhando novamente você usou `\s` e em seguida `\r\n`, acho melhor dar uma olhada em (O que significa o atalho \s nas REGEX?)[https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110701/14213]

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert Ops! Não precisava é do `\n?\r`, que vacilo kkkk, já arrumei e agradeço, novamente. :)

Comment: Obrigado amigos, o problema com o ponto e vírgula era em outra parte do meu código. Agora ele está funcionando corretamente. Obrigado.