# Como funciona o "lookahead positivo"(?=X) combinado com o "lookbehind positivo"(?<=X)?

Tags: regex

Após responder [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/246136/28595), e apesar de [conseguir perceber o que está ocorrendo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/246136/separar-strings-por-ponto-e-v%C3%ADrgula-mas-tamb%C3%A9m-guardar-o-ponto-e-v%C3%ADrgula#comment504693_246158) na expressão regular da minha resposta, fiquei curioso para saber como o trecho `((?<=;)|(?=;))` funciona.

[Li nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13600/28595) o que cada um faz, e também em outras várias fontes, mas confesso que não entendi bem como a expressão citada funciona.

Se possível, gostaria de uma explicação, pois estou tentando aprender *expressão regular* mas as explicações por ai são complicadas e com termos que muitas vezes eu não estou familiarizado.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Você já deve ter ouvido aquela frase que diz :

> Só porque você chegou no seu objetivo não significa que esteja certo

Pois bem, o que ocorreu com sua REGEX é o seguinte, vou explicar com outra para ficar mais claro.

```
/((?<=t)|(?=a)).+/
```

Explicação

- `((?<=t)|(?=a))` - Grupo em que uma das ocorrências deve ocorrer, dando preferencia para a primeira `(?<=t)`
- `.+` - Qualquer coisa o máximo que conseguir e tendo no mínimo 1.

Assim poderíamos desmembrar em duas REGEX :

- `/(?<=t).+/` - Qualquer coisa que vier depois de `t`
- `/(?=a).+/` - Qualquer coisa que tiver `a`

#### Testes

```
$regex = '~((?<=t)|(?=a)).+~';

$testes = array(
    'ana',
    'tania',
    'anastasia',
    'etilico',
    'aguilherme'
    'guilherme'
);

foreach ($testes as $k => $value){
    preg_match($regex, $value, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
}
```

#### Saida

```
[0] => ana
[0] => ania
[0] => anastasia
[0] => ilico
[0] => aguilherme
[0] =>
```

#### Retomando a sua REGEX `((?<=;)|(?=;))`

Ela é redundante, pois ambas estão verificando `;` assim se existe da sentença `(?=;)` então também vai ocorrer `(?<=;)`.
Contudo ha um porem, `(?<=...)` depende do que vem a seguir, de tal forma que se   for `.+`, mas a virgula vir no fim da sentença `;$`, a segunda parte não vai ser completada `.+`, assim caindo na segunda `(?=;)`.

#### Duvidas

Essa ultima explicação pode deixar um pouco confuso, qualquer duvida pergunte.

#### Adendo - quanto a sua duvida

> O problema que tive foi com o fato de quando usava o lookahead, a virgula não era isolada e quebrada em um indice pelo split do java quando ela vinha antecedida de outra string, e o inverso ocorria quando era o lookbehind [veja](http://ideone.com/yqWyjj) por isso a confusão para entender cada um.

O que ocorre é o seguinte :

Ambas as REGEX estão "explodindo" pela junção dos caracteres ([esse exemplo o grupo 2](https://regex101.com/r/60hW2a/1)), mas que `(?<=;)` é mais especifico que `(?=;)`, lembrando acima:

- `(?<=;)` - O que vier depois de `;`
- `(?=;)` - sentença que contenha `;`

Assim `(?<=;)` vai explodir pela junção que vem depois do `;` formando as palavras que você viu `pontoevirgula;`, `delinha;`.

Mas o `(?=;)` poderia explodir com ambos tanto o que vem antes quanto o que viria depois, contudo o split consome o caractere apos usá-lo, desta forma só ocorre a explosão pelo primeiro (que vem antes) gerando as outras palavras que você viu: `;espaco`, `;QUEBRA`

Comment: O problema que tive foi com o fato de quando usava o *lookahead*, a virgula não era isolada e quebrada em um indice pelo split do java quando ela vinha antecedida de outra string, e o inverso ocorria quando era o *lookbehind* veja: https://ideone.com/yqWyjj por isso a confusão para entender cada um.

Comment: @Articuno estou meio ocupado agora, jaja explico esse efeito, mas de antemão, tem a ver com o consumo do `;`

Comment: @Articuno Editado, veja se anda ficou duvidas

Comment: Entendi sim, sem abusar da sua boa vontade, então porque os dois combinados isolam o `;`?

Comment: Já que ele não está aqui, vou responder por ele.. Bem, na verdade sua expressão não vai isolar o `;`, o que está separando ele dos outros termos é o próprio `String#split();`. Caso não tenha entendido, veja [esta](https://prnt.sc/gy9ao7) foto. Seu regex está encontrando **dois** valores em posições diferentes (nulos), no caso, o split do Java apenas irá dividi-los. Veja [este](https://image.prntscr.com/image/GbZnjeLiRKi5mOobIC8Rpg.png) exemplo (espero não ter ficado muito confuso).

Comment: @Mateus exatamente isso, obrigado :D

Comment: @Mateus isso deveria ser outra resposta, complementando a do guilherme viu, entendi pela sua explicação somada a resposta dele.