# Expressão regular que localize padrões em que alguns termos podem mudar?

Tags: python, regex

Preciso localizar um padrão dentro de um texto. Exemplo:

```
PROJETO  Nº 1.100  DE 28 DE DEZEMBRO DE 2018.
```

Dentro deste padrão, a palavra `PROJETOS` pode ser também `PROTOCOLOS` e o caractere `º` pode ser `o`. Assim, a expressão deve encontrar:

```
PROJETO  Nº 1.100  DE 28 DE DEZEMBRO DE 2018.
PROJETO  No 1.100  DE 28 DE DEZEMBRO DE 2018.
PROTOCOLOS  Nº 1.100  DE 28 DE DEZEMBRO DE 2018.
PROTOCOLOS  No 1.100  DE 28 DE DEZEMBRO DE 2018.
```

Tentei desta forma:

```
re = r"(PROJETO|PROTOCOLOS)\s+N\s+\w\s+(\d\.?)+,?  DE  \d{1,2}  DE  \w{4,8}  DE  \d{4}."
```

**Obs**: Data pode ter ou não mais de um espaço

Comment: Por que em sua expressão regular há vários espaços em branco duplicados?

Comment: As informações de Projetos e Protocolos estão em uma base de dados e infelizmente não estão padronizado. Por ser muita informação, estou criando um tratamento de exceção. E obrigado pela edição, ajudou muito!!

Comment: Será que expressão regular é o ideal para isso? Com ela você precisará definir todas as variações e aparentemente é exatamente isso que você quer evitar.

Comment: A expressão regular está sendo utilizada para encontrar as variações aceitáveis e separar as radicais para tratar manualmente.

Comment: Tente esta regex: `(PROJETO|PROTOCOLOS)\s+N\s*(º|o)\s+\d+\.\d+,? {1,2}DE {1,2}\d{1,2} {1,2}DE {1,2}\w{4,8} {1,2}DE {1,2}\d{4}.` e a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/NHpdTF/1)

Comment: Talvez seja mais fácil fazer `re.split(r'\s+', texto)` para separar o texto por espaços -> `\s+` é um ou mais caracteres que correspondem a "espaços" (na verdade também inclui TAB, quebra de linha, e outros, [veja a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-29)). Assim, você tem uma lista com as partes do texto e pode validar cada uma individualmente (cada um com suas regras específicas). Acho que ficaria mais claro do que uma super-regex-que-valida-tudo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Resposta curta

Use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#splitting-strings) em vez de uma super-regex-que-faz-tudo.

### Resposta longa

Você pode, se quiser, tentar fazer uma única regex que resolve tudo (embora eu não ache que seja a melhor solução, continue lendo e entenda os motivos). Mas enfim, uma primeira tentativa seria algo como:

```
import re

r = re.compile(r"^(PROJETO|PROTOCOLOS)\s+N\s*(º|o)\s+\d+\.\d+,?\s+DE\s+\d{1,2}\s+DE\s+\w{4,9}\s+DE\s+\d{4}.$")
```

Usei os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` (início da string) e `$` (final da string) para delimitar que a string só pode ter o que coloquei na regex. Se você não usá-los, a regex pode dar *match* em strings que têm caracteres antes ou depois do texto que você quer (se este for o caso, basta remover o `^` e `$`).

Eu também uso `\s+` para o espaços. Esta expressão significa "um ou mais espaços", sendo que "espaços" podem ser: o próprio espaço em branco, um <kbd>TAB</kbd>, quebra de linha (`\n`), entre outros (veja a lista de completa de caracteres que `\s` considera [lendo a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-29) - [lembrando que esta lista pode variar de acordo com a linguagem e com a forma que a regex é criada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405703/112052)).

Se quiser **somente** o espaço em branco, pode usar um espaço em branco antes do `+`, em vez de `\s+`, ou ainda `[ ]+`, que na minha opinião fica um pouco menos confuso, pois dá para notar que há um espaço dentro dos colchetes. Usando algo como `etc +`, pelo menos para mim, não fica tão claro que há um espaço entre o `c` e o `+` (em expressões maiores eu tenho esse problema, mas aí é questão de gosto, tem gente que usa assim sem problema).

Os colchetes definem uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) e pegam qualquer coisa que estiver dentro deles. Ou seja, `[ ]` vai considerar somente o espaço (e não os demais caracteres que `\s` considera). Geralmente é redundante usar os colchetes para um único caractere, mas no caso do espaço, pode ser que dê mais legibilidade, conforme já explicado.

---

Esta expressão *parece* que considera tudo, mas há alguns problemas nela.

Você disse [nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/346146/express%C3%A3o-regular-que-localize-padr%C3%B5es-em-que-alguns-termos-podem-mudar#comment696668_346146) que quer "separar as radicais para tratar manualmente". Então você teria que colocar parênteses em volta dos trechos que quer capturar, [para que estes trechos possam ser recuperados depois](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Na regex acima, há somente dois pares de parênteses: `(PROJETO|PROTOCOLOS)` e `(º|o)`. Isso significa que somente estes trechos estarão disponíveis:

```
r = re.compile(r"^(PROJETO|PROTOCOLOS)\s+N\s*(º|o)\s+\d+\.\d+,?\s+DE\s+\d{1,2}\s+DE\s+\w{4,9}\s+DE\s+\d{4}.$")
textos = [
    "PROJETO Nº 1.100 DE 28 DE DEZEMBRO DE 2018.",
    "PROJETO No 1.100 DE 28 DE DEZEMBRO DE 2018.",
    "PROTOCOLOS Nº 1.100 DE 28 DE DEZEMBRO DE 2018.",
    "PROTOCOLOS No 1.100 DE 28 DE DEZEMBRO DE 2018."
]
for texto in textos:
    for match in r.finditer(texto):
        print(match.groups()) # imprimir os grupos de captura
```

A saída deste código é:

```
('PROJETO', 'º')
('PROJETO', 'o')
('PROTOCOLOS', 'º')
('PROTOCOLOS', 'o')
```

Repare que somente os trechos que estavam entre parênteses foram capturados. Se quiser o primeiro grupo, basta fazer `match.group(1)` (`match.group(0)` retorna a string inteira, que corresponde ao *match* encontrado pela regex).

Se quer capturar outros trechos da regex, coloque-os entre parênteses também, e eles estarão disponíveis no *match*. Por exemplo, para capturar o número do projeto e os campos da data:

```
r = re.compile(r"^(PROJETO|PROTOCOLOS)\s+N\s*(º|o)\s+(\d+\.\d+),?\s+DE\s+(\d{1,2})\s+DE\s+(\w{4,9})\s+DE\s+(\d{4}).$")
```

Com isso, os grupos serão:

```
('PROJETO', 'º', '1.100', '28', 'DEZEMBRO', '2018')
('PROJETO', 'o', '1.100', '28', 'DEZEMBRO', '2018')
('PROTOCOLOS', 'º', '1.100', '28', 'DEZEMBRO', '2018')
('PROTOCOLOS', 'o', '1.100', '28', 'DEZEMBRO', '2018')
```

---

### Outros problemas

Repare que mudei o nome do mês para `\w{4,9}` (4 a 9 caracteres), pois Fevereiro têm 9 letras (usando `{4,8}`, ele ficaria de fora). O problema é que `\w` aceita também números e o caractere `_`, então `abc_123` seria considerado um mês válido.

Outro ponto é o mês de Mar**ç**o. No Python 2 o `\w` só considera o `ç` se a [flag `UNICODE`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html#re.UNICODE) estiver setada (veja a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html) e um [exemplo](https://ideone.com/Y7q8iT)). Já no [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-31), o `ç` é considerado sem precisar da flag ([exemplo](https://ideone.com/aq2qrG)).

Também não ficou claro se o nome do mês sempre é com letras maiúsculas. De qualquer forma, `\w` aceita letras minúsculas, então talvez seja melhor ser mais especíco e usar `[A-ZÇ]{4,9}`, por exemplo (somente letras de `A` a `Z` ou `Ç`). Só que ainda sim, esta expressão ainda aceitará strings como `ABCDEF` ou até mesmo `ÇÇÇÇÇ` ([veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/l4XfBV/2)).

Então o melhor seria ter algo mais específico, como:

```
JANEIRO|FEVEREIRO|MARÇO|ABRIL|MAIO|JUNHO|JULHO|AGOSTO|SETEMBRO|OUTUBRO|NOVEMBRO|DEZEMBRO
```

Ou, se [quiser abreviar um pouco](https://regex101.com/r/qHyH1Q/2):

```
(JAN|FEVER)EIRO|MA(RÇ|I)O|ABRIL|JU[NL]HO|AGOSTO|(SETEM|OUTU|NOVEM|DEZEM)BRO
```

---

Para os dias, usar `\d{1,2}` vai aceitar qualquer valor entre `0` e `99`, então talvez seja melhor mudar para [algo que aceite somente valores de 1 a 31](https://regex101.com/r/NH2WKh/5). Por exemplo:

```
(trecho antes do dia) ... DE\s+(3[01]|[12]\d|[1-9])\s+DE ... (trecho depois do dia)
```

A mesma coisa para o ano, pois `\d{4}` vai aceitar desde `0000` até `9999`. Você pode trocar para algo como `(19|20)\d{2}`, que aceita anos entre 1900 e 2099. Ou colocar coisas ainda mais complicadas para restringir ainda mais este intervalo.

E para o número do protocolo/projeto, o número sempre terá o ponto como separador de milhares? Pode ter casos de números menores que 1000 (e portanto sem o ponto)? Acredito que não pode começar com zero (`01.200` seria inválido, certo?). Enfim, uma opção seria [esta regex](https://regex101.com/r/NH2WKh/6):

```
[1-9](([0-9]{0,2}(\.[0-9]{3})*)|[0-9]*)
```

Ela aceita valores como `1`, `123`, `1.100` e `1100` e rejeita valores que começam com zero (como `01` e `01.200`). Dá para melhorar mais, se você restringir somente para os números válidos nos seus casos de uso (se não tiver valores menores que 1000, por exemplo, ou se puder começar com zero, se o ponto separador de milhares for obrigatório retire o trecho `|[0-9]*` etc).

---

#### Agora é só juntar tudo

Bem, agora é só juntar todas as partes acima em uma única regex que valida tudo. Escolha se o separador será `\s+` ou `[ ]+`, coloque parênteses em volta dos grupos que quer capturar e pronto.

Se não quiser capturar algum par de parênteses, basta adicionar `?:` para que este se torne um [grupo de não-captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap). Por exemplo, se a palavra PROJETO ou PROTOCOLOS não me interessa, eu posso trocar para `(?:PROJETO|PROTOCOLOS)`, e com isso este trecho não será retornado no método `groups()`.

Mas espere, você vai querer validar a data também? Afinal, a regex pode até aceitar somente dias entre 1 e 31, mas e se tiver `31 de ABRIL` (que alguém pode ter digitado errado)? Abril só tem 30 dias, então a regex não deveria aceitar. O mesmo vale para 29 de fevereiro, que só é válido em anos bissextos. Enfim, [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15504877) tem uma regex para validar anos bissextos e veja que ela é tão complicada que começa a não valer mais a pena...

**É claro** que você poderia simplesmente usar `(\d{4})` para capturar o ano, e em seguida transformá-lo em número e então verificar se é bissexto. Inclusive, é o mais fácil, já que são apenas [alguns cálculos simples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30714165).

O mesmo vale para os demais campos (mês, número do projeto/protocolo), que é mais fácil extrair qualquer coisa que esteja lá e validar fora da regex. E já que vamos validar fora da regex, para que tentar fazer uma expressão super precisa e complicada?

Sendo assim, podemos levar esta ideia de "extrair o que tiver e validar fora da regex" ao extremo, fazendo simplesmente um `split`. Como as partes que você quer são separadas por espaços, basta fazer:

```
texto = "PROJETO Nº 1.100 DE 28 DE DEZEMBRO DE 2018."
# separar a string por espaços
partes = re.split(r"\s+", texto)
```

Eu usei `\s+` para separar a string por espaços (um ou mais espaços).
Novamente, você pode trocar por `[ ]+` se quiser somente o espaço em branco (e não quiser considerar o <kbd>TAB</kbd>, quebra de linha, etc).

Com isso, eu obtenho uma lista com as partes da string.
Então eu posso ver se eu tenho todas as partes (usando [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) para verificar o tamanho da lista), e a partir daí, eu posso validar cada parte separadamente.

A validação de cada parte é feita separadamente, de acordo com suas regras específicas. E aí pode ser com regex (versões mais simples), ou usando outros métodos, dependendo de cada caso. Ex:

```
if len(partes) == 9: # tem 9 partes, OK
    # como só há 2 opções, melhor fazer 2 comparações em vez de usar uma regex
    if partes[0] == 'PROJETO' or partes[0] == 'PROTOCOLOS':
        # primeira parte OK
    ... etc
```

E assim por diante. Para datas, você pode usar o módulo [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) para validá-las, por exemplo (mas isso já foge do escopo da pergunta, então deixo como "exercício para o leitor" ).

---

Claro que eu também poderia fazer um meio-termo: uma regex não tão precisa, mas que valida um formato básico. Algo como a primeira versão que coloquei no início, mas com alguns grupos de captura adicionais para extrair as informações mais complicadas de validar (data, número), e então faço a validação fora da regex.

Mas já que a maioria das validações (pelo que parece) são mais fáceis de fazer fora da regex, acho que o `split` acaba sendo a solução mais fácil.

Outro ponto é que na pergunta você menciona a palavra `PROJETOS` (no plural), mas nos exemplos tem a palavra `PROJETO` (no singular). Se tanto faz plural ou singular, você pode usar `(PROJETO|PROTOCOLO)S?` (O `S?` indica que a letra "S" é opcional).

De qualquer forma, a ideia geral não muda, basta mudar a regex e/ou a validação de acordo com o que precisar.

Answer (score 3):

Tente essa regex `(PROJETO|PROTOCOLOS) *?N(º|o) *?[0-9.]+ *DE *\d+ DE \b.*\b DE \d*\.` com a flag global, que por *default* é executado no método `regex.finditer(string)`

Então no seu código ficaria assim:

```
import re

test_str = ("PROJETO Nº 1.100 DE 28 DE DEZEMBRO DE 2018.\n"
"PROJETO No 1.100 DE 28 DE DEZEMBRO DE 2018.\n"
"PROTOCOLOS Nº 1.100 DE 28 DE DEZEMBRO DE 2018.\n"
"PROTOCOLOS No 1.100 DE 28 DE DEZEMBRO DE 2018.")
pattern = r'(PROJETO|PROTOCOLOS) *?N(º|o) *?[0-9.]+ *DE *\d+ DE \b.*\b DE \d*\.'
regex = re.compile(pattern)
for match in regex.finditer(test_str):
    print "%s" % (match.group(0))
```

---

**Explicação da Regex**:

- `(PROJETO|PROTOCOLOS)` - Captura a sequencia: PROJETO ou a sequencia PR

OTOCOLOS

- `*` - Captura de 0 a infinitos espaços em branco (não da para ver direito com a formatação de código, o conteúdo da regex é " *").
- `N(º|o)` - Captura N com `º` ou `o` em seguida.
- `*` - Captura de 0 a infinitos espaços em branco.
- `[0-9.]+` - Captura uma combinação que possua números e pontos (`.`).
- `*` - Captura de 0 a infinitos espaços em branco.
- `DE` - Captura exatamente a sequencia "DE".
- `*` - Captura de 0 a infinitos espaços em branco.
- `\d+` - Captura 1 ou mais dígitos.
- `DE` - Captura exatamente a sequencia " DE ".
- `\b.*\b` - Captura uma palavra (qualquer sequencia de caracteres que tenham no início e no final o fim da string, início da string ou espaços).
- `DE` - Captura exatamente a sequencia " DE ".
- `\d*` - Captura 0 ou infinitos dígitos.
- `\.` - Captura o ponto final da frase

[Você também pode ver o funcionamento e testar outros padrões de regex aqui.](https://regex101.com/r/hjboUm/2)

**OBS**: A regex está o mais genérica possível, se tiver algum caso onde houve um resultado inesperado me informe qual é que podemos deixar a regex mais assertiva.