# Regex pegar o valor da linha anterior

Tags: regex

Texto o texto abaixo e gostaria de pegar o valor da linha acima da palavra `"OUTRAS INFORMAÇÕES"`, neste caso o valor `8.571.962,06`.

Fiz da seguinte forma, mais estou achando muito vulnerável:

```
^(.*?)\s*(?<valor>\d+.\d+.\d+,\d+|\d+.\d+.\d+,\d+|\d+.\d+,\d+|\d+,\d+))\s*OUTRAS INFORMA.*?.*?ES
```

Texto:

```
NOME: TESTE DE SILVA SAURO
CPF: 785.981.970-84
DECLARAÇÃO DE AJUSTE ANUAL
IMPOSTO SOBRE A RENDA - PESSOA FÍSICA
EXERCICIO 2018 ANO-CALENDÁRIO 2017
EVOLUÇÃO PATRIMONIAL
Bens e direitos em 31/12/2016
Bens e direitos em 31/12/2017
Dividas conus rcais em 31/12/2016
Divisas e ônus reais em 31/12/2017
100.580.873.91
100.329. 110,32
9135,456,07
8.571.962,06
OUTRAS INFORMAÇÕES
Rendimentos isentos e não tributáveis
```

Estou utilizando o site [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/) e o programa Rad Software Regular Expression Designer.

Comment: Testei no site do RegExr com a expressão [\d\.\,]*(?=\W\nOUTRAS INFORMAÇÕES) e consegui pegar apenas o valor. Usei positive lookahead e character set.

Comment: Por favor clique em **[edit]** e adicione a linguagem/ferramenta que está usando, pois cada uma implementa regex de um jeito e o que funciona pra uma pode não funcionar pra outra. E não entendi o "vulnerável". De qualquer forma, não é mais simples ir lendo as linhas uma a uma (guardando uma referência para a anterior) e quando a linha for "OUTRAS INFORMAÇÕES", vc pega a anterior e encerra o loop? Ou tem várias linhas com "OUTRAS INFORMAÇÕES" e vc só quer quando tiver um valor específico acima? (no caso, um valor monetário)

Comment: Sim, encerro o loop. Eu pego o primeiro valor anterior a palavra "OUTRAS INFORMAÇÕES" (Neste caso uma linha acima).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Não conheço em detalhes o software que você está usando, mas como você está testando no site [regexr.com](https://regexr.com), vou assumir que os recursos [PCRE](https://www.pcre.org/) estão disponíveis. (basicamente existem vários "*flavors*" diferentes de regex e existe muita variação entre as linguagens e ferramentas, então deixo abaixo uma solução mais geral, que deve funcionar para o seu caso)</sup>

---

Não entendi porque você acha sua regex "vulnerável". Talvez ela não seja a mais eficiente, já que tem várias [alternâncias](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (o caractere `|`, que faz com que ela teste cada uma das alternativas até encontrar uma) e muitas delas são meio redundantes (você testa várias combinações diferentes de números separados por pontos e vírgulas).

O número que você quer pegar parece ser um valor monetário, sempre usando o ponto como separador dos milhares e a vírgula para separar os centavos. Então você pode usar:

```
\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2}
```

Você estava usando `\d+`, que significa "um ou mais dígitos", então `\d+,\d+` aceita valores como `12345,12345`. Usando [quantificadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) mais específicos é possível limitar as quantidades exatas que precisamos.

No caso, `\d{1,3}` é "no mínimo 1 e no máximo 3 dígitos". Em seguida tenho o trecho entre parênteses `(?:\.\d{3})`, que é "ponto, seguido de **exatamente** 3 dígitos". E logo depois dos parênteses temos `*`, que significa "zero ou mais ocorrências". Isso quer dizer que todo este trecho "ponto seguido de 3 dígitos" pode se repetir várias vezes (ou nenhuma). Isso garante que serão aceitos valores como `1,23`, `123,12`, `1.212,21` e `8.571.962,06`.

Em seguida, você usou `\s`, que realmente pega as quebras de linha, mas também pega espaços e o caractere <kbd>TAB</kbd> (entre outros, [a lista exata varia conforme a linguagem/ferramenta/*engine*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405703/112052)). Neste caso o valor que você quer (`8.571.962,06`) não possui espaços e por isso "funciona", mas se quiser limitar apenas para quebras de linha, pode usar apenas `\n`.

Se quiser ser ainda mais específico, pode usar `(?:\r\n?|\n)`: isso considera um `\r` (quebras de linha do OS X), um `\r` seguido de `\n` (quebras de linha do Windows) ou apenas um `\n` (quebras de linha do Unix). Então a regex fica [assim](https://regexr.com/4ako1):

```
\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2}(?=(?:\r\n?|\n)OUTRAS INFORMAÇÕES(?:\r\n?|\n))
```

Isso retorna somente a linha anterior à "OUTRAS INFORMAÇÕES", mas somente se ela for um valor monetário no formato indicado (se o número não tiver pontos e a vírgula, ou tiver a quantidade errada de dígitos, a regex não encontra nada).

Repare que para a linha "OUTRAS INFORMAÇÕES" eu usei um [*lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (indicado por `(?=`). A ideia do *lookahead* é que ele só verifica se algo existe, mas esse algo não é incluído no *match*. Por isso a regex encontra somente a linha anterior, deixando o próprio "OUTRAS INFORMAÇÕES" de fora do resultado.

---

Se a linha anterior tiver mais algum texto antes do valor monetário, a regex acima [ignorará e pegará apenas o valor](https://regexr.com/4akr1).

Se quiser ser ainda mais específico e só pegar este valor caso ele seja a única informação na linha, pode incluir `^` no início da regex, **com um detalhe**: normalmente o `^` significa "início da string", mas várias linguagens e ferramentas possuem uma opção que faz com que ele mude seu significado para "início da linha". No regexr.com esta opção é chamada "multiline" (marque ela no botão "flags", no canto superior direito). Cada ferramenta tem seu próprio jeito de configurar isso, veja como é na que você está usando. A regex fica [quase igual à outra](https://regexr.com/4akqi), apenas com um `^` no início:

```
-- Só funciona com a opção "multiline" ativada, pois o ^ passa a ser "início da linha"
^\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2}(?=(?:\r\n?|\n)OUTRAS INFORMAÇÕES(?:\r\n?|\n))
```

Assim, a regex só encontrará um *match* se a linha tiver **somente** o valor monetário.

---

Reparei que no seu texto existe um espaço no final de cada linha. Neste caso, basta adicionar `\s*` (zero ou mais espaços) na regex, tanto depois do valor monetário quanto depois de "INFORMAÇÕES":

```
\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2}(?=\s*(?:\r\n?|\n)OUTRAS INFORMAÇÕES\s*(?:\r\n?|\n))
```

---

Por fim, algumas *engines* possuem o atalho `\R`, que corresponde a uma quebra de linha, então a regex também poderia ser:

```
^\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2}(?=\ROUTRAS INFORMAÇÕES\R)
```

Comment: para pegar o valor 3 linhas acima, como ficaria? `100.329.110,32`

Comment: @user2254936 Basta adicionar `(?:(?:\r\n?|\n).*){2}` para pegar 2 linhas antes de "OUTRAS INFORMAÇÕES": https://regexr.com/4qaj1 - só uma dica: se tiver outra dúvida diferente, o ideal é [fazer outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (pesquisando antes se já não existe no site, claro), pois aí a pergunta fica visível pra todos na página principal e vc tem mais chances de alguém responder. Comentando aqui, menos gente vê (provavelmente só eu), e ultimamente estou sem mto tempo pra dedicar ao site, ou seja, vc tem menos chance de obter uma resposta rápida...

Answer (score 0):

Testei bo [regerx](https://regexr.com/) e pareceu dar certo
`(.+)\nOUTRAS INFORMAÇÕES`

Em python

```py
import re
str = """
NOME: TESTE DE SILVA SAURO
CPF: 785.981.970-84
DECLARAÇÃO DE AJUSTE ANUAL
IMPOSTO SOBRE A RENDA - PESSOA FÍSICA
EXERCICIO 2018 ANO-CALENDÁRIO 2017
EVOLUÇÃO PATRIMONIAL
Bens e direitos em 31/12/2016
Bens e direitos em 31/12/2017
Dividas conus rcais em 31/12/2016
Divisas e ônus reais em 31/12/2017
100.580.873.91
100.329. 110,32
9135,456,07
8.571.962,06
OUTRAS INFORMAÇÕES
Rendimentos isentos e não tributáveis 
"""

program = re.compile('(.+)\nOUTRAS INFORMAÇÕES')
program.findall(str)
```