# REGEX extrair tudo de um grupo

Tags: regex

Estou tentando extrair algumas informações de um HTML, porém a regex não funciona, tenho quase certeza que não está pegando espaços, algo assim.

https://regex101.com/r/LPJO4Z/1

```
<g-card(.*?)>(.*?)<\/g-img>
```

Se eu remover `<\/g-img>` do final funciona, mas não pega todo o grupo que quero que seria `<g-card>...</g-img>`.

Comment: Se é de um HTML, por que não faz pelo DOM?

Comment: Não estou usando PHP, estou fazendo em Java

Comment: da uma lida aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/q/457684/5988245 tmj

Comment: @LipESprY caramba, usei o Jsoup, ficou ate melhor + a ajuda do carinha da regex ficou perfeito, obrigado.

Comment: Que bom que fui útil! E, de forma alguma, queria desmerecer a resposta do mestre @hkotsubo! A questão é que parsear HTML com RegEx quando se existe uma lib para isso é "tiro no pé", por mais que funcione! Mas de qualquer forma, a sua pergunta **é sobre regex**. ;D

Comment: @LipESprY Eu já fui mais radical e achava que **nunca** devemos usar regex para trabalhar com HTML (é só "caçar" alguns comentários antigos meus por aí). Mas ultimamente estou ficando mais flexível, e dependendo do caso, pode ser uma solução válida. Se for um **trecho específico** (algumas tags, poucos níveis de aninhamento, etc), entradas controladas (nada de CDATA e outras estruturas mais complexas), e vc fizer algumas concessões e até aceitar alguns falsos positivos, acho OK. Dito isso, para o caso específico dessa pergunta, talvez um *parser* de HTML seja mais adequado... :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo Confesso que compartilho da sua opinião. Mas a RegEx é mais para casos estáticos, que só vai rodar uma única vez, onde **tem um padrão fixo** e/ou que não dependa de "mexer na RegEx" para cada texto... Particularmente, curto "brincar com RegEx". Mas no final, é mais seguro o parser HTML (lib). ;O

Comment: Bem no final de tudo usei os 2 métodos e consegui o resultado exatamente como queria, eu tinha feito uma regex para tudo, mas não funcionava deve ser algum limite em bytes já que era um HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por padrão, o ponto [não considera as quebras de linha](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html), então `.*` só vai até a próxima quebra de linha e não consegue ir adiante (e como o `g-img` não está na mesma linha do `g-card`, ele não encontra nada).

Muitas linguagens e ferramentas possuem uma opção para mudar este comportamento, e geralmente é chamada de "DOT_ALL" ou "single line" (que é um nome meio confuso para o que a opção faz, mas enfim).

No site [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) basta escolher a opção "single line" (clique na bandeira no canto direito, logo depois da regex), isso fará com que o ponto também considere as quebras de linha. [Veja](https://regex101.com/r/JrsLnc/1) que com esta opção ativada, são encontrados os *matches* corretamente.

Outra opção é trocar o ponto por `[\s\S]`:

```
<g-card([\s\S]*?)>([\s\S]*?)<\/g-img>
```

Basicamente, `\s` corresponde a "espaços, <kbd>TAB</kbd> e quebras de linha" ([o significado exato muda de uma linguagem/engine/ferramenta para outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405703/112052), mas quebras de linha sempre são consideradas) e `\S` é "tudo que não for `\s`". Ou seja, `[\s\S]` é "tudo que for e que não for quebras de linha": basicamente um "ponto turbinado", pois corresponde a qualquer caractere, inclusive as quebras de linha (independente da opção "single line" estar ativada ou não, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/JrsLnc/2)).

---

De qualquer forma, usar regex para manipular HTML [nem sempre é a melhor solução](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454). Muitas vezes um *parser* de HTML é a melhor opção.

Comment: `[\s\S]` foi suficiente pra +1! kkkk

Comment: @LipESprY A primeira vez que vi esse "truque" não parecia fazer sentido, mas depois que entendi, achei bem legal :-)

Comment: Caramba você me salvou +1