# Regex usando preg_replace para separar valores de acordo com ") "

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Estou precisando utilizar uma separação de string pelas ocorrências do **fechamento do parênteses e um espaço após**, com a seguinte técnica eu consegui fazer:

```
preg_replace('/[\)][\s]/', '$0--> $1', '1 () 2 () 3 ()');
```

saída:

```
1 () --> 2 () --> 3 ()
```

Gostaria de saber se está correto ou existe uma forma melhor do regex `'/[\)][\s]/'` para pegar essa ocorrência?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quando você só quer pegar um único caractere, não precisa dos colchetes:

```
preg_replace('/\)\s/', ') --> ', '1 () 2 () 3 ()');
```

Resultado:

```
1 () --> 2 () --> 3 ()
```

Os colchetes definem uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Ex: `[abc]` significa "a letra `a` **ou** a letra `b` **ou** a letra `c`" (apenas uma delas).

Por isso, `[\)]` é o mesmo que `\)`. O mesmo vale para o `\s`. Quando você só precisa pegar um caractere, os colchetes são desnecessários.

---

No caso acima, estou substituindo o "fechamento de parênteses seguido de espaço" por `') --> '`, e esse é o modo mais simples e direto.

O modo como você fez também funciona, mas além dos colchetes há outro detalhe: você usou as variáveis `$0` e `$1`.

A primeira (`$0`) não tem problema usar, já que ela corresponde a todo o trecho encontrado pela regex (o fechamento de parênteses mais o espaço). Já a segunda (`$1`) estará em branco, pois ela corresponde ao [primeiro grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Mas como sua regex não tem grupos de captura, essa variável não estará preenchida e pode até ser retirada. Então assim funcionaria também:

```
preg_replace('/\)\s/', '$0--> ', '1 () 2 () 3 ()');
```

---

Só lembrando que o `\s` também corresponde ao caractere <kbd>TAB</kbd> e a quebras de linha (veja a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)), além de outros caracteres ([a lista exata pode variar de uma linguagem para outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405703/112052)). Se quer limitar a sua regex para **somente o espaço em branco**, troque o `\s` por um espaço:

```
preg_replace('/\) /', '$0--> ', '1 () 2 () 3 ()');
```

Ou:

```
preg_replace('/\) /', ') --> ', '1 () 2 () 3 ()');
```

Repare que há um espaço entre o `)` e o `/`.

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado pela ajuda, tenho que estudar bastante, pois trabalhar com essas funções e regex é bem complexo, muita informação e detalhes para dominar!

Comment: cheguei atrasado né... =)

Comment: @AndreiCoelho É, o *timing* é tudo, né :-)

Comment: @RobertCezar Regex de fato é um assunto bem amplo e complexo, e que parece não ter fim. Dois sites muito bons são [esse](https://www.regular-expressions.info) e [esse](http://rexegg.com), que tem tutoriais e artigos interessantes. E 2 livros (um pouco mais avançados) são [esse](https://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124) e [esse](https://www.amazon.com/Regular-Expressions-Cookbook-Solutions-Programming/dp/1449319432)