# RegEx para duas hipóteses de string simultaneamente

Tags: regex

Possuo a seguinte entrada, e faço uma interação linha por linha em todas.

```
D      b1308 pspE; thiosulfate sulfurtransferase PspE   K03972 pspE; phage shock protein E
B  09193 Unclassified: signaling and cellular processes-6
C    99977 Transport
D      b2347 yfdC; inner membrane protein YfdC  K21990 yfdC; formate-nitrite transporter family protein
D      b3657 yicJ; putative xyloside transporter YicJ   K03292 TC.GPH; glycoside/pentoside/hexuronide:cation symporter, GPH family
D      b3876 yihO; putative sulfoquinovose transporter  K03292 TC.GPH; glycoside/pentoside/hexuronide:cation symporter, GPH family
D      b0361 insD-1; IS2 element protein    K07497 K07497; putative transposase
D      b1402 insD-2; IS2 insertion element protein InsB K07497 K07497; putative transposase
```

Entretanto usando o seguinte RegEx para cada linha extrair o nome do gene (por exemplo `b2347 yfdC`):

```
[b]\d{4}\s[a-zA-z]{3,4}
```

Mas este RegEx não extrai o nome inteiro em casos como `b1402 insD-2`.

Existe um único RegEx para que se extraia ambos os casos?

Comment: O formato é sempre 3 ou 4 letras, seguidos opcionalmente de "hífen + 1 número"?

Comment: Ou é o sem hífen ou com hífen, formato sempre de 3-4 letras, e sim hífen e um número

Comment: Coloquei uma resposta "genérica", mas se estiver usando alguma linguagem/site/ferramenta específica, pode [edit] a pergunta e adicionar essa informação, pois cada linguagem implementa regex de um jeito e nem sempre tudo funciona do mesmo jeito em todas

Comment: Eu acabei de testa-la, está perfeita, obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar esta regex:

```
b\d{4}\s[a-zA-Z]{3,4}(-\d)?
```

Detalhe: os colchetes definem uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Por exemplo, `[ab]` significa "a letra `a` **ou** a letra `b`" (qualquer uma delas). Mas quando você quer somente uma única letra, não precisa dos colchetes. Sendo assim, `[b]` é o mesmo que `b`, por isso removi os colchetes em torno do `b`.

Outro detalhe é que você estava usando `[a-zA-z]` (com o `z` minúsculo duas vezes). Isso funciona por coincidência, já que `A-z` é o intervalo entre `A` e `z`, e se você olhar na [tabela ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) verá que este intervalo pega todas as letras maiúsculas e minúsculas. O problema é que neste intervalo também existem outros caracteres, como o `[`, `\` e `]`. Então é melhor deixá-los de fora e usar o intervalo correto: `[a-zA-Z]` (com `Z` maiúsculo no final).

Por fim, se você quer pegar tanto `yihO` quanto `insD-1`, use:

- `[a-zA-Z]{3,4}`: para pegar de 3 a 4 letras
- `(-\d)?`: um hífen seguido de um dígito (`\d`). Eu envolvo tudo entre parênteses e coloco um `?`, que torna todo esse grupo opcional

Veja esta regex funcionando no [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/S1L2r8/1).

---

Só lembrando que `\s` *geralmente* (na maioria das linguagens/engines) corresponde não só aos espaços em branco, mas também a outros caracteres, como o <kbd>TAB</kbd> e quebras de linha ([a lista exata de caracteres varia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405703/112052)). Se quiser que a regex considere apenas o espaço em branco, basta trocar para:

```
b\d{4} [a-zA-Z]{3,4}(-\d)?
```

Repare que agora há um espaço entre o `\d{4}` e o `[`.