# Pegar somente o trecho final após a barra com expressão regular

Tags: regex, google-sheets

Dei uma procurada geral aqui e no Google e cheguei a achar alguma coisa que funcionou parcialmente.

Possuo o seguinte padrão de texto:

```
030.000.208   OUTRA COISA
001.005.001   ALGUMA / COISA AQUI COM - TAMBÉM / GERAL.ASSINADA-COISA
040.001.218   OUTRA COISA / AQUI OUTRA/COISA GERAL
000.000.003   ALGUMA / COISA AQUI COM - TAMBÉM
```

Em resumo, o texto possui um padrão onde começa com uma sequência de números, três espaços em branco, um texto (que pode possuir pontuações), um espaço em branco, uma barra e um espaço em branco, outro texto (que pode possuir pontuações) etc.

O que preciso é que SOMENTE seja selecionado o texto que vem no final, após a última ocorrência do espaço-barra-espaço.

Seguindo o exemplo acima, o retorno para cada linha seria:

```
OUTRA COISA
GERAL.ASSINADA-COISA
AQUI OUTRA/COISA GERAL
COISA AQUI COM - TAMBÉM
```

Estou usando a seguinte expressão regular: `\/ ([^\/]*)$`

Ela está retornando isso:

```
GERAL.ASSINADA-COISA
COISA AQUI COM - TAMBÉM
```

Estou apanhando muito e não encontro solução, alguém pode dar uma luz?

Vou utilizar a expressão regular no Google Sheets.

Comment: Bom, sua primeira linha não tem o caractere / portanto não atende a expressão regular, e não entendi porque em sua terceira linha você espera "OUTRA/COISA GERAL" e não "AQUI OUTRA/COISA GERAL".

Comment: Corrigi o resultado esperado. foi erro de digitação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Você disse que está usando o Google Sheets, mas não disse se o texto todo está na mesma célula. Na solução abaixo, estou assumindo que cada linha está em uma célula diferente (isso torna a solução mais simples, inclusive).</sup>

---

Uma alternativa é usar esta regex:

```
 ^\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\s{3}(?:.*/ )?(.+)$
```

Os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$` são, respectivamente, o início e fim da string. Assim eu garanto que só vou tratar as strings que seguem rigidamente este formato.

Depois temos `\d{3}`, que significa "3 dígitos" (o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d` corresponde a um dígito de 0 a 9, e o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{3}` significa "3 ocorrências"), seguido de `\.` (o caractere ponto). Como o ponto por padrão possui significado especial em regex ([corresponde a qualquer caractere - exceto quebras de linha](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)), ele precisa ser escapado com `\` para que seja interpretado como um caractere comum.

Depois temos mais 3 dígitos, outro ponto e mais 3 dígitos, seguidos de `\s{3}` (3 espaços).

Depois disso temos `(?:.*/ )?`. Os parênteses com `(?:` formam um [grupo de não-captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) (e posteriormente entenderemos o motivo de usá-lo). O grupo todo é `(?:.*/ )`, que é `.*` (zero ou mais caracteres), seguido de barra, seguido de espaço (repare que há um espaço antes do `)`). E o `?` logo depois [torna todo este trecho opcional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html).

Ou seja, eu posso ter vários caracteres seguidos de barra + espaço, ou não. Isso serve tanto para o primeiro caso (que não tem nenhuma barra), quanto para os demais. E também me aproveito do fato do quantificador `*` ser [ganancioso](http://rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedytrap) e tentar pegar o máximo possível de caracteres. Isso significa que a expressão acaba pegando até a última barra que seja seguida de espaço (que é exatamente o que queremos).

Em seguida temos `(.+)`, que é `.+` (um ou mais caracteres), dentro de parênteses, o que forma um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

A expressão completa que usei no Google Sheets é:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "^\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\s{3}(?:.*/ )?(.+)$", "$1")
```

A função [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245) pega o valor de uma célula (no exemplo acima é "A1"), aplica a regex e faz a substituição. No terceiro parâmetro, que indica a substituição a ser feita, eu usei a variável especial `$1`, que corresponde ao primeiro grupo de captura (no caso, o `(.+)`).

É por isso que usei um grupo de não-captura no trecho anterior, pois aí a regex não cria um grupo à toa (já que este não é usado na substituição).

O resultado é:

```
String original                                                       | Após REGEXREPLACE
----------------------------------------------------------------------|-------------------------
030.000.208   OUTRA COISA                                             | OUTRA COISA
001.005.001   ALGUMA / COISA AQUI COM - TAMBÉM / GERAL.ASSINADA-COISA | GERAL.ASSINADA-COISA
040.001.218   OUTRA COISA / AQUI OUTRA/COISA GERAL                    | AQUI OUTRA/COISA GERAL
000.000.003   ALGUMA / COISA AQUI COM - TAMBÉM                        | COISA AQUI COM - TAMBÉM
```

Você pode ver a planilha [aqui](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16SFhcFCj-NPlGfBEnAvI0qJ_oZmrWCwhzRNXO1kYNu4/edit?usp=sharing), e a regex em funcionamento [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/xeYVvZ/6/).

---

Um detalhe é que o `\s` corresponde a vários caracteres, como espaço, <kbd>TAB</kbd> e quebras de linha ([a lista exata pode variar de acordo com a linguagem/ferramenta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405703/112052) - no caso do Google Docs, [ele usa a *engine* RE2](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en), cuja sintaxe pode ser consultada [aqui](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt)). Se quiser que a regex considere somente espaços, pode mudar para:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1, "^\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3} {3}(?:.*/ )?(.+)$", "$1")
                    tem um espaço aqui ^
```

Repare que agora, em vez de `\s`, há um espaço em branco antes do `{3}`.

Comment: Perfeito... funcionou exatamente como precisava... e as explicações de como está sendo tratado a expressão ficaram muito claras. Me ajudou muito e ainda aprendi mais sobre esse mundo de expressões regulares que eu apanho pra caramba pra entender...

Valeu!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde @ludo Man, vc precisa seguir exatamente esse regra? 
"O que preciso é que SOMENTE seja selecionado o texto que vem no final, após a última ocorrência do espaço-barra-espaço" 
se a resposta for sim essa regexp Que voce mostrou funciona " / ([^/]*)$ "

O seu exemplo esperado esta assim:

030.000.208   OUTRA COISA

001.005.001   ALGUMA / COISA AQUI COM - TAMBÉM / GERAL.ASSINADA-COISA

040.001.218   OUTRA COISA / AQUI OUTRA/COISA GERAL

000.000.003   ALGUMA / COISA AQUI COM - TAMBÉM

Mas para que a expressão funcione como quer o exemplo deveria estar assim:

030.000.208   / OUTRA COISA

001.005.001   ALGUMA / COISA AQUI COM - TAMBÉM / GERAL.ASSINADA-COISA

040.001.218   OUTRA COISA / AQUI OUTRA / COISA GERAL

000.000.003   ALGUMA / COISA AQUI COM - TAMBÉM

Pode verificar nesse link : https://regex101.com/r/7dtEZK/1

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.... mas é exatamente este o problema.
Não consigo modificar a fonte, mas preciso que o resultado exibido seja o que exemplifiquei.