# Como criar expressão regular para buscar números em parênteses?

Tags: regex

Estou tentando criar uma Regex para pegar números que estão em parênteses. Assim:

```
1) Pergunta 1  
2) Pergunta 2  
3) Pergunta 3  
4) Pergunta 4  
.  
.  
10) Pergunta 10
```

Até agora consegui chegar nisso: `(^[0-9].* )`

Mas não pegou o `10)`.

Necessariamente eu preciso pegar o número, o parênteses e o espaço depois.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisa escapar o parênteses com uma barra para a regex não considerá-la parte da expressão, e a expressão "[0-9]" pode ser trocada por "\d":

```
^(\d+\)\s)
```

Answer (score 6):

Uma opção é usar:

```
^(\d+\) )
```

Os parênteses possuem [significado especial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) em regex, então para que ela capture o próprio caractere `)`, você deve escrevê-lo como `\)`. E repare que há um espaço entre o `\)` e o último `)`, para que a regex pegue o espaço depois do parênteses.

Eu também usei o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` em vez de `*`, pois o `*` significa "zero ou mais ocorrências" (ou seja, se não tiver nenhum dígito, também serve), enquanto o `+` significa "uma ou mais ocorrências" - assim eu garanto que deve ter pelo menos um dígito. (se eu usar `*`, a regex pode pegar linhas que não tem dígitos no início, como `) etc...` - [veja](https://regex101.com/r/EQH6r9/2/)).

Eu coloco o trecho que quero entre parênteses (os números, `\)` e espaço), pois assim eles formam um grupo de captura que contém todo este trecho, assim ele pode ser facilmente recuperado depois. Veja no [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Wvw4Tp/2/) que os grupos ficam destacados em verde (e veja que, graças ao `+` em vez de `*`, ela não pega mais as linhas que não tem dígitos).

E o [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` garante que este trecho só será verificado no início da string.

---

Você também pode trocar `\d` por `[0-9]`. Dependendo da linguagem/*engine* não fará diferença, mas em algumas o `\d` pode aceitar quaisquer caracteres da [categoria Unicode "Number, Decimal Digit"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm), o que inclui caracteres como `٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩`, entre outros (veja [esta resposta](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/414230) para mais detalhes). Se você sabe que seus textos não possuem tais caracteres, tanto faz usar um ou outro. Mas se quiser limitar a somente os dígitos de 0 a 9, use `[0-9]` em vez de `\d`.

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/388123/112052) sugeriu usar `\s` em vez do espaço (que também funciona). Mas este atalho também corresponde a outros caracteres, como quebras de linha (`\n`, `\r`), <kbd>TAB</kbd>, entre outros ([também varia conforme a linguagem/*engine*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405703/112052)). Se quiser que a regex pegue somente o espaço em branco, use o que eu sugeri acima.

Comment: Muito boa sua explicação. Obrigado. Vai ajudar bastante gente.