# Regex para validar uma quantidade específica de aparições da sequência " - "

Tags: regex

Preciso aplicar o um padrão regex para um título. O regex é salvo no banco e o título somente é aceito caso esteja dentro do padrão.

O padrão é o seguinte:

> texto - texto - texto

Neste título devem ocorrer somente duas vezes o " - ", e caso ocorram mais vezes, o texto é invalidado.

Os textos podem conter qualquer caractere, menos a sequência que o divide (" - ").
Já tentei várias combinações e ainda não cheguei ao resultado esperado, ex:

```
^([\wÀ-ú\- ]+( - )[\wÀ-ú\- ]+( - )[\wÀ-ú\-]+)$
```

Comment: Tente algo como `^[^-]+ - [^-]+ - [^-]+$`

Comment: Eu testei no site [ https://regexr.com/ ] e apenas tirando a parte **\-** já teve o resultado que você procura **^([\wÀ-ú ]+ - [\wÀ-ú ]+ - [\wÀ-ú]+)$**

Comment: Se estiver usando alguma linguagem de programação, é mais fácil fazer o split e verificar se o resultado tem 3 itens não vazios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Você não disse qual linguagem ou programa está usando, o que facilitaria, pois com uma linguagem de programação seria muito mais fácil fazer o `split` e verificar se a lista tem 3 elementos não vazios - [exemplo](https://ideone.com/MfMux6). De qualquer forma, segue uma solução que deve funcionar para a maioria das engines/linguagens.*</sup>

---

Sua regex não funciona por causa do `[\wÀ-ú\- ]`. Os colchetes definem uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), que pegam qualquer caractere que esteja entre eles. E repare que dentro deles tem `\-`, que corresponde ao hífen. Ou seja, este trecho também pega um hífen, que é justamente o que você não quer. (inclusive, por causa disso, esta regex considera que textos como `- - - - -` são válidos, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/JkPoJr/2/)).

Se quer que tenha somente dois hífens, e entre eles não tenha nenhum outro, você pode simplesmente tirá-los dos colchetes:

```
^[\wÀ-ú ]+ - [\wÀ-ú ]+ - [\wÀ-ú]+$
```

Repare que também removi os parênteses, pois eles me parecem desnecessários aqui. [Veja a diferença para a regex anterior](https://regex101.com/r/JkPoJr/3/).

Como a parte `[\wÀ-ú ]+ -`  se repete duas vezes, a regex também poderia ser:

```
^([\wÀ-ú ]+ - ){2}[\wÀ-ú]+$
```

Agora faz sentido colocar parênteses, pois tudo que está dentro deles é repetido duas vezes (indicado pelo [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `{2}`). [Veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/JkPoJr/4/) a regex funcionando.

Inclusive esta construção é útil para variar a quantidade de repetições. Se quiser exatamente 5 ocorrências, por exemplo, troque o `{2}` para `{5}`. Se quiser no mínimo 2 ocorrências, sem limite máximo, use `{2,}`, e se quiser no mínimo 2 e no máximo 5, use `{2,5}`.

---

Apenas alguns detalhes para complementar:

O [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\w` corresponde a letras, números e o caractere `_`. Este último caractere costuma não ser lembrado pelas pessoas, e muitas vezes a regex acaba pegando coisas que não devia por causa dele (por exemplo, a regex considera que o texto `_ - ____ - _` é válido, [veja](http://regex101.com/r/JkPoJr/5/)). Isso acontece por causa do [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`, que significa "uma ou mais ocorrências". Ou seja, `[\wÀ-ú ]+` pega uma ou mais ocorrências de qualquer caractere que se encaixe no que está entre colchetes. Como o `_` se encaixa no `\w`, então vários `_` também é considerado válido pela regex.

Além disso, dependendo da linguagem/*engine*/programa, o `\w` pode considerar somente letras de `a` a `z` (maiúsculas e minúsculas) e dígitos de 0 a 9, **ou** considerar todas as letras e números definidos pelo Unicode (incluindo caracteres acentuados e letras de outros alfabetos, como o japonês, árabe, russo, etc). Como não foi especificado qual linguagem está sendo usada, não dá para sugerir como alterar (algumas possuem opções/parâmetros/*flags* que fazem o `\w` se comportar de um jeito ou de outro).

Se o `\w` considerar todas as letras definidas pelo Unicode, você não precisaria usar o intervalo `À-ú`, por exemplo. Lembrando que este intervalo inclui todos os caracteres entre os code points U+00C0 e U+00FA, que você pode ver quais são consultando [esta lista](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/latin_supplement/list.htm). Repare que nesta lista há caracteres que não são letras, como o `÷` ([DIVISION SIGN](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f7/index.htm)). Ou seja, a regex considera que o texto `÷÷ - ÷ - ÷÷÷` é válido ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/JkPoJr/6/)).

<sup>*Para saber mais sobre o que é um code point, [veja esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052).*</sup>

Outro detalhe é que `[\wÀ-ú\- ]+` também possui um espaço antes do `]`, o que quer dizer que um texto com vários espaços entre os hífens, como     `-    - x`, também é considerado válido ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/JkPoJr/7/)).

Então se quiser melhorar a regex e evitar esses falsos positivos, você terá que ser mais específico. Ou, se suas entradas são controladas (por exemplo, se o texto é gerado por algum processo que garante que sempre haverá algo significativo entre os hífens e "nunca" terá os casos estranhos já citados), então não tem problema ficar com a regex mais simples.

Se for o caso, você pode simplificar mais ainda e usar uma [classe de caracteres negada](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), para pegar qualquer coisa que **não** seja um hífen:

```
^([^-]+ - ){2}[^- ]+$
```

No caso, `[^-]` é "qualquer caractere que não seja um hífen", e `[^- ]` é "qualquer caractere que não seja hífen ou espaço" (já que esta última não tinha o espaço).

Só lembrando que a primeira opção não pega as quebras de linha, já esta opção pega ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/JkPoJr/9/)). Se quiser evitar que pegue as quebras de linha, basta incluí-las na classe de caracteres negados:

```
^([^-\n\r]+ - ){2}[^-\s]+$
```

O primeiro caso `[^-\n\r]` exclui hífen e quebras de linha, já o segundo tem o atalho `\s`, que pega o espaço e quebras de linha (além de vários outros caracteres, mas [a lista exata varia conforme a linguagem/*engine*/programa utilizado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405703/112052)). Assim, a regex não pega mais as quebras de linha entre os hífens ([veja](https://regex101.com/r/JkPoJr/10/)).

---

Enfim, dá para ficar especulando sobre opções diferentes para considerar ou não determinados casos, mas como você não especificou como é o texto (se começa sempre com letra, se pode ter números (quantos e em quais posições, se tanto faz, etc), quantidade de espaços entre as palavras, etc), acredito que aqui já temos o suficiente para você começar.

Você disse que entre os hífens tem "qualquer caractere", mas é realmente qualquer um? O Unicode atualmente define mais de 130 mil caracteres, e duvido que você realmente queira aceitar todos eles, já que nem todos fazem sentido em todos os contextos. Dependendo de como estão os seus textos e do quanto você aceita lidar com falsos positivos (caso ocorram), pode ir ajustando a regex para deixá-la mais específica.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, ajudou bastante. Um detalhe que eu editei na pergunta mas ainda não foi aceito é que podem ocorrer outros hífens no meio do texto, o que não pode ocorrer novamente é o espaço hífen espaço ( - ). Então algo do tipo: texto-pre - texto - texto-pós, pode ocorrer. É nessa repetição de hífens está a questão. Tem alguma forma de fazer isto? Estou usando Java, mas gostaria de resolver tudo no regex, pois existem outros  padrões.

Comment: @giovannijakubiak Aí vai depender muito do que pode ter no texto (o hífen sempre está entre letras? pode ter outros caracteres? etc). Por exemplo, se for sempre letras e o hífen sempre possui uma letra antes e outra depois, uma alternativa é https://regex101.com/r/jM2CPS/1/ (lembrando que nesse caso eu estou usando o `\w` no modo Unicode, ou seja, ele já pega as letras acentuadas)

Comment: @giovannijakubiak Se está usando Java, eu ainda acho mais fácil fazer `texto.split(" - ")` e ver se o resultado é um array de 3 posições (e para cada posição vc verifica se ela é um texto válido, podendo até usar uma regex mais simples). Se for o caso, vc pode até fazer outra pergunta com exemplos mais específicos, dizendo exatamente as regras que definem o que é um texto válido, etc

Comment: regex101.com/r/jM2CPS/1 é a solução ideal . Fui alterando uma das suas alternativas e cheguei nessa solução https://regex101.com/r/JkPoJr/4/ , porém ali desconsidero espaços. Muito obrigado pela ajuda, salvou o chamado! Sobre o Java, estou buscando deixar o código bem genérico por causa dos outros padrões regex existentes, logo não seria ideal colocar especificidades de determinados títulos no código. Agradeço novamente!