# Regex pegar valor entre duas palavras

Tags: regex

Estou precisando pegar o valor `62.715,90` entre as palavras `TOTAL` e `DEDUÇÕES`. No OCR consta a quebra de linha conforme texto abaixo.

Estou usando o software Regular Expressio Design.

```
NOME: TESTE DE SILVA SAURO  
CPF: 785.981.970-84  
IMPOSTO SOBRE A RENDA - PESSOA FÍSICA  
DECLARAÇÃO DE AJUSTE ANUAL  
EXERCICIO 2018 ANO-CALENDÁRIO 2017  
TOTAL  
>62.715,90  

DEDUÇÕES
```

Minha expressão: `TOTAL\n\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2}\nDEDU.*?ES`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se foi um problema ao copiar e colar, mas depois de "TOTAL" tem alguns espaços, e antes do número tem um `>`. Se for isso, colocar somente `\n` não vai adiantar. Uma alternativa é usar:

```
TOTAL\s+>\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2}\s+DEDU.*?ES
```

Em vez de `\n`, eu uso o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s`, que já [contempla espaços e quebras de linha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405703/112052). Eu também uso o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`, que significa "uma ou mais ocorrências". Ou seja, pode ter várias quebras de linha e espaços depois de "TOTAL".

Depois tem o próprio caractere `>`, e em seguida o trecho correspondente ao valor numérico.

Não sei se o software que você está usando tem suporte a grupos de captura. Caso tenha, basta colocar o trecho correspondente aos números entre parênteses:

```
TOTAL\s+>(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2})\s+DEDU.*?ES
```

Assim, o valor estará disponível no primeiro grupo de captura (veja por exemplo no [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/PZlZaF/1/), do lado direito aparece "Group 1" com somente o valor que você precisa).

---

Se não tiver o `>` antes do valor, basta retirá-lo da regex:

```
TOTAL\s+(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2})\s+DEDU.*?ES
```

Comment: Utilizando o software de Regex e não deu :( ... Software: Regular Expression Designer.

Comment: @user2254936 O texto é exatamente como está na pergunta? (com espaços depois de "TOTAL" e `>` antes do valor?) Se não tiver o `>`, basta retirá-lo da regex, por exemplo. Testei aqui com a versão free do Regular Expression Designer e funcionou

Comment: não tem espaço depois do TOTAL e não tem > antes do valor.

Comment: @user2254936 Então é só tirar o `>` da regex: `TOTAL\s+(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2})\s+DEDU.*?ES` (atualizei a resposta com essa opção)

Comment: realmente, retirando > funcionou .... valeu demais !

Answer (score 0):

Talvez haja um outro modo mas consegui pensar na seguinte expressão: `TOTAL[\n]+([0-9.,]+)[\n]+DEDUÇÕES`:

```js
const reg = /^TOTAL[\n]+([0-9.,]+)[\n]+DEDUÇÕES$/gm;
const input = `TOTAL

62.715,90

DEDUÇÕES`;

var match = reg.exec(input);
console.log(match.filter(a => /^[0-9,.]+$/.test(a)));
```

Comment: O problema de `[0-9.,]+` é que também considera válidas strings como `...` e `,,,`, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/q2Ebws/1/)

Comment: @hkotsubo tem razão, não tinha pensando nisso. Muito obrigado pelo aviso  vlw