# Como funciona o metacaractere \t em uma regex?

Tags: r, regex

Tenho esta variável:

```
y <- c('stack overflow', 'user number  2', 'nova\nlinha', 'nova \n linha')
```

E estas funções com os respectivos resultados:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Com `\n`:

```
str_detect(string = y, regex(pattern = '\\n'))

[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Com `\s`:

```
str_detect(string = y, regex(pattern = '\\s'))
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Nas strings `'nova\nlinha', 'nova \n linha'`, enquanto que na primeira não existe espaços mas na segunda sim, o retorno da função é `TRUE` para ambos os casos.

Tentei usar o `\t`, como consta [nesta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583111/regular-expression-find-spaces-tabs-space-but-not-newlines):

```
str_detect(string = y, regex(pattern = '[ \\t]'))
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Funcionou corretamente.

Bom, aí fiquei com algumas dúvidas. Na documentação de `regex`, `\t` opera de outra forma. Ele procura por um `tab` na string. Tenho duas perguntas frente a isso:

- qual a diferença de `tab` para espaçamento e em que situações `tabs` são mais comuns que espaços?
- por que a última função que escrevi funcionou? Eu a usei, mas não entendi sua lógica (esta aqui: `str_detect(string = y, regex(pattern = '[ \\t]'))`).

**NOTA**: Uso `R` em `Linux` e é preciso usar a dupla barra (`\\`) para operar ao invés de uma (`\`). Assim, por exemplo, ao invés do convencional `\s` deve-se usar o `\\s`.

Comment: Eu respondi sobre a regex, mas quanto ao uso de TAB x espaço, acho que é um assunto amplo demais que foge ao escopo da regex: https://www.google.com/search?q=tab+vs+space

Comment: [Leitura recomendada sobre "tabs vs espaços".](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57/tabs-versus-spaces-what-is-the-proper-indentation-character-for-everything-in-e)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sim, `\t` procura por um TAB. O último caso funciona porque os colchetes formam uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), e a regex encontra um *match* caso a string tenha qualquer caractere pertencente à classe.

No caso, `[ \\t]` é uma classe que contém um espaço e um TAB (`\t`) - repare que há um espaço depois do `[` - então se a string tiver **qualquer um** desses caracteres, já serve (ela não precisa ter todos, basta um deles existir na string que a regex já encontra um *match*). Nenhuma das strings possuem um TAB, mas a primeira, segunda e quarta possuem um espaço, por isso o resultado é `TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE`.

Tanto que se você retirar o espaço dos colchetes:

```
str_detect(string = y, regex(pattern = '[\\t]'))
```

Dará `FALSE` para todas as strings, pois agora a classe de caracteres só tem o TAB (não tem mais o espaço), e nenhuma das strings possui um TAB (mas se uma das strings fosse por exemplo `'com\tTAB'`, aí daria `TRUE`).

*Se bem que nesse caso, a expressão poderia ser apenas `'\\t'`, já que não há ganho nenhum em usar uma classe de caracteres que possui apenas um caractere.*

---

Já o `\s` é um [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) que corresponde a espaço, TAB ou quebras de linha ([podendo variar seu significado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405703/112052) conforme a linguagem ou *engine* utilizada). Por isso ele detecta o `\n` na terceira string, mesmo ela não tendo nenhum espaço ou TAB.