# RegEx para capturar espaços, exceto dentro de aspas

Tags: php, regex

Gostaria de uma expressão regular (PHP) para excluir os espaços duplos fora de aspas.

```
update tabela set¬
   nome='alberto da   silva',¬
   telefone='1234'¬
)
```

Quero capturar espaços duplos, enters, tabs fora das aspas.

Eu dei uma lida, e só cheguei até `/\s{2,}/`.

Mas como eu condiciono isso a não pegar dentro das aspas?

Comment: Fabio, a resposta abaixo resolveu o problema ou ficou faltando alguma coisa? Caso tenha resolvido, você pode aceitar a resposta, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. Caso não tenha resolvido, basta [edit] a pergunta explicando o que faltou.

Answer (score 2):

Antes de mais nada, vale lembrar que `\s` corresponde a espaços, TABs, quebras de linha, [entre outros caracteres](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405703/112052). Então se tiver um espaço e depois uma quebra de linha, `\s{2,}` vai considerar esses dois caracteres como uma coisa só.

<sup>*Antes a pergunta dizia para capturar esses espaços, [depois pediu para remover](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/447732/revisions). Abaixo tem uma solução para ambos os casos.*</sup>

---

Uma maneira de resolver isso é tentar capturar algo que esteja entre aspas, e caso consiga, descartar este *match*. Ou, se não tiver nada entre aspas, pegar a sequência de dois ou mais `\s`:

```
//coloquei 2 espaços depois de "set"
$str = "update tabela set  
   nome='alberto da   silva',
   telefone='1234'
)";
if (preg_match_all('/\'[^\']*\'(*SKIP)(*F)|[^\'\s]*(\s{2,})[^\s\']*/', $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0)) {
    foreach ($matches as $m) {
        if (count($m) > 1) { // grupo de captura preenchido (número não está entre aspas)
            var_dump($m[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

A regex usa [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (o caractere `|`, que significa **ou**), com 2 opções.

A primeira é `\'[^\']*\'(*SKIP)(*F)`:

- `\'[^\']*\'`: começa e termina com aspas (que por estar dentro de uma string delimitada por `'`, deve ser escrito como `\'`), e entre as aspas tem `[^\']*` ([zero ou mais caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) que **não** são `'`)
- `(*SKIP)(*F)`: são "[verbos de controle](http://www.rexegg.com/pcre-doc/08.37/pcrepattern.html#SEC27)" que... controlam a *engine* de regex. Neste caso, elas fazem com que a regex "desista" do *match* encontrado (ou seja, ela descarta o texto que está entre aspas) - existe uma explicação mais detalhada sobre estes "verbos" [aqui](http://rexegg.com/backtracking-control-verbs.html#skipfail). Buscar o texto e depois descartá-lo me pareceu mais simples que fazer várias verificações antes e depois dos espaços para detectar que eles fazem parte de um texto que está entre aspas.

A segunda opção é `[^\'\s]*(\s{2,})[^\s\']*`:

- `[^\'\s]*`: zero ou mais caracteres que não sejam `\s` nem `'`
- `(\s{2,})`: dois ou mais `\s`, entre parênteses para formar um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)

Como a regex só pode pegar a palavra entre aspas ou a sequência de `\s`, há casos em que o grupo de captura estará preenchido (quando pegar os `\s`) e casos em que não estará (quando não encontrar 2 ou mais `\s`, ou encontrar texto entre aspas).

Sendo assim, dentro do `foreach` eu verifico se existe o grupo de captura (o array `$m` terá mais de um elemento). A saída é:

```
string(7) "  
   "
string(5) "
   "
```

Ou seja, 2 ocorrências: uma corresponde aos espaços depois de "set", mais a quebra de linha, mais os espaços antes de "nome". A segunda é a quebra de linha depois de "silva'," mais os espaços antes de telefone".

Obs: se a string tiver uma quebra de linha do Windows, que consiste de 2 caracteres (`\r\n`), então estas também serão capturadas por `\s{2,}`.

[Veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/KA4XKb/1/) a regex funcionando.

---

Para ficar um pouco mais fácil de "ver" os caracteres, você pode imprimir o valor da [tabela ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) de cada caractere:

```
if (preg_match_all('/\'[^\']*\'(*SKIP)(*F)|[^\'\s]*(\s{2,})[^\s\']*/', $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0)) {
    foreach ($matches as $m) {
        if (count($m) > 1) { // grupo de captura preenchido (número não está entre aspas)
            for($i = 0; $i < strlen($m[1]); $i++) {
                echo ord($m[1][$i]), ",";
            }
            echo PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Saída:

```
32,32,10,32,32,32,
10,32,32,32,
```

Sendo que 32 é o espaço e 10 é o *new line* (`\n`).

---

[Nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/447732/regex-para-capturar-espa%C3%A7os-exceto-dentro-de-aspas/447747?noredirect=1#comment859282_447747) você disse que quer usar [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), então na verdade você não quer capturar ([como estava anteriormente na pergunta, antes de ser editada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/34fbf56b-da8f-4ae6-8f8b-0c4f4c926c40/view-source)), e sim substituir estes espaços.

Bom, eliminar totalmente os espaços não parece ser a opção mais adequada, pois a string tem uma query e se deixar sem espaços ela ficará inválida. Então, supondo que você queira trocar os espaços/quebras de linha/etc por apenas um espaço, daria para adaptar a regex acima:

```
echo preg_replace('/\'[^\']*\'(*SKIP)(*F)|([^\'\s]*)\s{2,}([^\s\']*)/', '$1 $2', $str);
```

É muito parecida, só que agora eu coloco os grupos de captura em volta dos `[^\'\s]*` antes e depois do `\s{2,}`. E eu substituo por `'$1 $2'` (o conteúdo do primeiro par de parênteses, seguido de um único espaço, seguido do conteúdo do segundo par de parênteses). Assim, eu troco a sequência de dois ou mais `\s` por um único espaço. A saída é:

```
update tabela set nome='alberto da   silva', telefone='1234'
)
```

Se quiser eliminar somente os espaços (mas não as quebras de linha), mude para:

```
echo preg_replace('/\'[^\']*\'(*SKIP)(*F)|([^\' ]*) {2,}([^ \']*)/', '$1$2', $str);
```

A saída passa a ser:

```
update tabela set
nome='alberto da   silva',
telefone='1234'
)
```

---

Mas se a ideia é remover dois ou mais espaços, ou um TAB, ou uma quebra de linha, uma opção é:

```
echo preg_replace('/\'[^\']*\'(*SKIP)(*F)|([^\'\s]*)(?: {2,}|[\t\n\r])+([^\'\s]*)/', '$1 $2', $str);
```

O trecho `(?: {2,}|[\t\n\r])` é uma [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) com duas opções:

- `{2,}`: dois ou mais espaços (repare no espaço antes do `{`)
- `[\t\n\r]`: um TAB ou quebra de linha (incluindo o `\r` para pegar as quebras de linha do Windows

Todo este trecho pode ocorrer uma ou mais vezes (pois tem um `+` depois indicando a repetição). Tudo isso é trocado por um único espaço (pois eu coloquei espaço entre `$1` e `$2`).

Tudo isso está entre um grupo de não-captura (marcado pelo `(?:`), assim eu não crio grupos extras e posso continuar usando `$1 $2` no segundo parâmetro (se eu não usasse `?:`, seria criado outro grupo e eu teria que mudar o parâmetro para `$1 $3`, já que agora a regex teria 3 grupos).

Saída:

```
update tabela set nome='alberto da   silva', telefone='1234' )
```

---

Por fim, se a ideia é remover **exatamente** dois espaços (e não "dois ou mais"), basta trocar `{2,}` por `{2}`.

Comment: a ideia era usar um preg_replace...

Comment: @FabioCarpi vc disse que queria capturar, não substituir. Por favor edite a pergunta e coloque exatamente o que vc quer fazer

Comment: @FabioCarpi Atualizei a resposta

Comment: Obrigado. Eu disse na pergunta "espaços DUPLOS", porque no meu editor, a tabulação é substituída por 2 espaços...

Comment: @FabioCarpi O que exatamente você quer substituir? Dois ou mais espaços? Exatamente 2 espaços? E troca por apenas um espaço ou por nenhum? Tabs, quebras de linha, e outros, também são trocados? De qualquer forma, eu dei 2 opções de replace, uma que troca tudo por um único espaço, e outra que troca apenas 2 ou mais espaços por nenhum (e mantém tabs e quebra de linha). Mas se o seu caso for "exatamente 2 espaços" (e não "2 ou mais"), troque o `{2,}` por `{2}`

Comment: Desculpe amigo. Eu query tratar as querys pra fazer um log. Então quero tirar espaços{2,}, tabs, enters, fora das aspas.

Comment: @FabioCarpi Coloquei mais uma opção de replace na resposta

Comment: @FabioCarpi Vi que tinha um erro no último replace, já corrigi