# Como identificar palavras que iniciam com um caractere e termina com o mesmo acrescido de um espaço utilizando regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
/(\*[ ]|\_|\~|\@\@|\%\%)([^\s].*?)\1/gm
```

Quando adiciono a expressão \*[ ] (destacada em vermelho) para considerar o espaço após o * ele passa a considerar em todos os lugares sendo que eu preciso que seja somente no final da palavra.

Então o que eu preciso fazer no regex é que seja considerado * seguido de qualquer caractere no inicio e *  com espaço somente no final.

Em verde destaquei as palavras que quero capturar com a expressão.

Estou tentando realizar essa operação em JS.

Comment: Por favor clique em **[edit]** e coloque o código (no caso, a regex) como texto. Colocá-lo como imagem não é o ideal, entenda os motivos [lendo o **FAQ**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/112052). Aproveitando, seria bom colocar também a linguagem ou ferramenta/engine que está usando, pois cada uma implementa regex de um jeito e o que funciona pra um pode não funcionar pra outro

Comment: Feito, @hkotsubo! Obrigado pelas orientações

Comment: Aliás, a regex tem coisas que não parecem ter a ver com o caso: `\*[ ]` pega um asterisco seguido de espaço (por isso que pega o penúltimo caso), e tem outras coisas não inclusas na descrição do problema, como o `\_` e `\~`, por exemplo (parece que tem coisas a mais aí) - Entre os asteriscos pode ter qualquer coisa? Ou só "palavras" (letras e/ou dígitos, etc). Se for qualquer coisa, então poderia ter outros asteriscos e/ou espaços, sinais de pontuação, etc... dependendo do que precisa, a regex será diferente...

Comment: Use `'(\*).+\1\s'`, se a engine suportar backreference: https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html

Comment: Se bem que, nesse caso, **eu acho** que bastaria tirar o espaço depois do asterisco, ou seja,  retirar o `[ ]` e deixar somente `\*` - Ah, o primeiro caso de teste não tem espaço depois do segundo `*`, (ou tem e eu que não vi?) então ele deveria ser pego pela regex?

Comment: Ou ainda `/(\*|\_|\~|\@\@|\%\%)([^\s].*?)\1 /gm` (asterisco sem espaço depois, seguido de vários caracteres, termina com asterisco e espaço (repare que tem um espaço antes da última barra). Quanto ao `gm` no final, depende de como vc está fazendo a busca (`g` serve pra trazer todas as ocorrências, é útil se a string tem mais de uma e vc quer todas, e `m` serve pra mudar o comportamento do `^` e `$`, mas como a regex não tem isso, então o `m` não serve pra nada nesse caso)

Comment: @Lucas Essa regex também pega o penúltimo caso (`* Teste*`), mas entendi que ele só quer os que estão marcados em verde...

Comment: Pessoal, muito obrigado pela ajuda! Com a orientação de vcs consegui evoluir aqui, obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende do que você precisa, mas pelos casos reportados, as regras parecem ser:

- depois do primeiro asterisco não pode ter espaço (ou seja, não é "qualquer caractere" como dito na pergunta)
- depois do segundo asterisco tem que ter um espaço

Então seria algo do tipo:

```
/(\*)[^\s][^*]*\* /
```

Ou seja, tem o asterisco, depois tem um caractere que não é espaço (`[^\s]`), depois tem zero ou mais caracteres que não sejam asterisco (`[^*]*`), e depois tem o próprio asterisco seguido de espaço (repare que tem um espaço antes da segunda barra).

Se bem que isso não vai pegar o primeiro caso (`*Teste*`), pois parece que não tem espaço depois do segundo asterisco. Neste caso, se quiser também pegar asterisco no final, teria que ser:

```
/(\*)[^\s][^*]*(?<! )\*( |$)/
```

No final temos `( |$)` (um espaço ou o final da string), mas antes do segundo asterisco também incluí um [*lookbehind negativo*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) para garantir que antes dele não tenha um espaço (senão ele também pegaria `*Teste *`, mas você deu a entender que não é pra pegar esse caso).

---

E claro que isso serve apenas para o asterisco, mas sua regex está considerando vários outros casos, como `_`, `~`, `@@` e `%%`, então ficaria:

```
/(\*|_|~|@@|%%)([^\s].*?)\1 /
```

Ou, se quer considerar o caso em que a segunda ocorrência pode estar no final (e não necessariamente seguida de espaço), além de não poder ter espaço antes da segunda ocorrência:

```
/(\*|_|~|@@|%%)([^\s].*?)(?<! )\1( |$)/
```

Ex:

```js
var regex = /(\*|_|~|@@|%%)([^\s].*?)(?<! )\1( |$)/;
var textos = ['*Teste*', '*Teste *', '*Teste*ok', '* Teste* ok', '*Teste* ok', '@@teste@@'];
for (var texto of textos) {
    if (regex.test(texto)) {
        console.log(texto);
    }
}
```

---

Lembrando que as *flags* `gm` que você usou podem ou não fazer diferença:

- o `g` busca todas as ocorrências (ou seja, se a string tiver mais de uma trará todas). Se quer apenas pegar uma ocorrência, o `g` não é necessário
- o `m` muda o comportamento do `$`: o normal é ele indicar apenas o final da string, mas com o `m`, o `$` também indica o final de uma linha

Por fim, o atalho `\s` não pega só espaços, pois ele também pode considerar outras coisas, como TAB e quebras de linha ([veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405703/112052) para mais detalhes). Se quiser apenas espaços, troque-o por um espaço simples mesmo.