# Removendo espaços em branco encontrados entre todos os caracteres "|" dentro de uma determinada string

Tags: php

Possuo uma pequena aplicação em PHP que armazena diversas palavras-chaves em uma mesma linha do banco de dados. As palavras, por suas vez, encontram-se separadas pelo caractere "|".

Exemplo de linha gravado no banco de dados:

```
Palavra 01|Palavra 02|Palavra 03|Palavra 04
```

A partir disso, eu faço o explode das palavras e gero um array. Desta forma, consigo realizar as rotinas necessárias em minha aplicação. Funciona perfeitamente!

Eu gostaria, portanto, de organizar melhor o registro dessas palavras no banco de dados, visto que, em alguns deles há ocorrências de espaços em branco entre o caractere "|", conforme mostrado neste segundo exemplo abaixo:

```
Palavra 01    |   Palavra 02   | Palavra 03    |    Palavra 04
```

Observe no exemplo a ocorrência de um ou mais espaços entre os caracteres.

Estou em busca de uma função no PHP que realize o tratamento desse tipo de string, removendo todos os espaços em branco encontrados entre os referidos caracteres. O resultado então, seria exatamente conforme o mostrado no primeiro exemplo.

Obs: Cada string pode conter um número variado de palavras. As palavras nem sempre são únicas, existindo tambem palavras compostas. Por isso não é possível fazer uso do comando replace para remoção dos espaços em branco, já que ele removeria também o espaço em branco da palavra chave composta.

Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Se forem só palavras únicas, basta fazer um replace retirando os espaços.

Comment: Não e só palavras únicas. Há palavras compostas tbm. Vou ajustar a pgta. Obgd amigo.

Comment: Exploda o texto com [`preg_split()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-split.php)

Comment: Uma alternativa é `implode('|', array_map('trim', explode('|', $str)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma forma é usando [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace.php) com a expressão regular:

```
/\s{0,}\|\s{0,}/
```

Vai buscar o caractere `|` precedido e/ou seguido ou não de espaço(s), e se encontrar, substitui pelo próprio caractere `|`. Exemplo:

```
$str = 'Palavra 01    |Palavra 02   | Palavra 03    |    Palavra 04';
$pattern = '/\s{0,}\|\s{0,}/';
echo preg_replace($pattern, '|', $str); // Palavra 01|Palavra 02|Palavra 03|Palavra 04
```

[**Teste no IDEONE**](https://ideone.com/5C6Y7f)

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado Sam, pelo apoio.

Comment: Só um detalhe, em vez de `{0,}` pode usar `*` (ambos significam "zero ou mais ocorrências"). Vale lembrar também que `\s` não pega só espaços, ele também considera TAB, quebra de linha e [outros caracteres](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405703/112052). Claro que no exemplo da pergunta não tem esses caracteres e não faz diferença, mas se quiser garantir que só pegue espaço, poderia ser `/ *\| */` (repare no espaço antes do `*`)