# Regex que aceite apenas string vazia e números

Tags: javascript, regex

Preciso de um Regex que aceite somente uma **string vazia** da minha **input** ou **números**, atualmente estou fazendo desta forma:

```
const setAmount = (text:string) =>{ 
  const value = /^[0-9.]+$/;
  
   // Parar a aplicação caso seja diferente de números[0-9] ou string vazia ' '
   if(!value.test(text)){ 
     return;
    }
   .... continuação
```

Porém esse Regex que tenho só válida se existe números.

Comment: string vazia (`''`) é diferente de espaço em branco (`' '`). que é o que representou.

Comment: Pensei que fosse a mesma coisa, afinal qual é a diferença entre elas?

Comment: @GabrielMarianoOliveira `''` é uma string vazia (sem "nada", de tamanho zero), e `' '` é uma string contendo um espaço em branco - ela tem tamanho 1, pois tem um caractere, que é o espaço - apesar da gente não "ver", é um caractere que ocupa... espaço :-)

Answer (score -5):

Fala pessoal consegui achar uma solução para meu problema, bastava deixar um espaço no final do meu array de regex e alterar o simbolo de adição por pelo *, ficando desta forma:

```
const value = /^[0-9. ]*$/;
```

Comment: Existe uma representação padrão para espaço em branco é o `\s` (`contra-barra + S`). Utilizando a contrabarra sei o mais indicado pois ele casa o padrão com algumas representações alternativas de espaço em branco, por exemplo o `tab`.

Comment: O problema é que se digitar somente vários espaços, a regex também aceita (não sei se é a intenção). Se a ideia é aceitar somente "vazio ou números", basta trocar o `+` por `*`. Aliás, se digitar vários pontos (`.....`), a regex também aceita. Enfim, tem que ver o que vc realmente precisa... E sobre o `\s` que o @Danizavtz comentou, tem mais detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405703/112052)

Comment: @hkotsubo, eu achava que o \s pegava o `&nbsp` também, aquele caractere espaço em branco não separável. Gostei da referência.

Comment: @Danizavtz Na verdade ele pega o `&nbsp;` sim, veja [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes) que o `\s` é equivalente a `[ \f\n\r\t\v\u00a0\u1680\u2000-\u200a\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000\ufeff]` (repare no `\u00a0`, que corresponde ao no-break space) - aquela lista que tem no início da resposta (espaço, TAB, `\n`) são os que sempre tem em qualquer linguagem, o resto varia...